# What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git commit ranges?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-diff, git-log, git-rev-list

Some Git commands take commit ranges and one valid syntax is to separate two commit names with two dots `..`, and another syntax uses three dots `...`.

What are the differences between the two?

Comment: Related: [Git diff .. ? What's the difference between having .. and no dots](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7251477/456814).

Answer (score 294, accepted):

It depends on whether you're using a `log` command or a `diff` command. In the `log` case, it's in the `man git-rev-parse` documentation:

> To exclude commits reachable from a commit, a prefix ^ notation is used. E.g. ^r1 r2 means commits reachable from r2 but exclude the ones reachable from r1.
>
> This set operation appears so often
>   that there is a shorthand for it. When
>   you have two commits r1 and r2 (named according to the syntax explained in
>   SPECIFYING REVISIONS above), you can
>   ask for commits that are reachable
>   from    r2 excluding those that are
>   reachable from r1 by "^r1 r2" and it
>   can be    written as "r1..r2".
>
> A similar notation "r1...r2" is
>   called symmetric difference of r1 and
>   r2 and    is defined as "r1 r2 --not
>   $(git merge-base --all r1 r2)". It is
>   the set of    commits that are
>   reachable from either one of r1 or r2
>   but not from both.

Which basically means that you'll get all commits that are in either of the two branches, but not in both.

In the `diff` case, it's in the `man git-diff` documentation:

> ```
>   git diff [--options] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>...]
>
>       This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to
>       the second <commit>, starting at a common ancestor of both
>       <commit>. "git diff A...B" is equivalent to "git diff
>       $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can omit any one of <commit>, which
>       has the same effect as using HEAD instead.
> ```

Which is a bit fuzzy. Basically it means it shows only the differences in that branch compared to another branch: it looks for the last common commit with the first committish you gave it, and then diffs the second committish to that. It's an easy way to see what changes are made in that branch, compared to this branch, without taking notice of changes in this branch only.

The `..` is somewhat simpler: In the `git-diff` case, it's the same as a `git diff A B` and just diffs A against B. In the `log` case, it shows all commits that are in B but not in A.

Comment: It's pretty ridiculous how the meaning of `..` and `...` is exactly swapped for log and diff: `log A..B` is changes from merge base to B which is what `diff A...B` does

Comment: @phiresky Yeah, that is really poor usability. I recommend not to use the dot notations for `git diff`.

Comment: Does this mean `A...B` == `A..B + B..A`?

Comment: @Danon for `git log` this is absolutely yes

Comment: @Danon but for `git diff` it's the opposite! `git diff A..B` == `git diff A...B + git diff B...A` !

Comment: @phiresky I'm embarrassed to admit how many years I used git while believing I was just really bad at remembering which one was two-dots and which one was three-dots -- never noticing that the times I "mixed them up" were correlated with which git command I was using.‍♂️

Answer (score 996):

## Using Commit Ranges with Git Log

When you're using commit ranges like `..` and `...` with `git log`, the difference between them is that, for branches A and B,

```
git log A..B
```

will show you **all of the commits that B has that A doesn't have**, while

```
git log A...B
```

will show you ***both*** the commits that A has and that B doesn't have, and the commits that B has that A doesn't have, or in other words, **it will filter out all of the commits that both A and B share, thus only showing the commits that they *don't* both share**.

### Visualization with Venn Diagrams & Commit Trees

Here is a visual representation of `git log A..B`. The commits that branch B contains that don't exist in A is what is returned by the commit range, and is highlighted in red in the Venn diagram, and circled in blue in the commit tree:

[image: "git log A..B" diagram][image: Tree 1]

These are the diagrams for `git log A...B`. Notice that the commits that are ***shared*** by both branches are not returned by the command:

[image: "git log A...B" diagram][image: Tree 2]

### Making the Triple-Dot Commit Range `...` More Useful

You can make the triple-dot commit range `...` more useful in a log command by using the `--left-right` option to show which commits belong to which branch:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --left-right --graph master...origin/master
< 1794bee (HEAD, master) Derp some more
> 6e6ce69 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Add hello.txt
```

In the above output, you'll see the commits that belong to `master` are prefixed with `<`, while commits that belong to `origin/master` are prefixed with `>`.

## Using Commit Ranges with Git Diff

Someday I might add my own explanation for how the commit ranges work with `git diff`, but for now, you might want to check out [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git diff commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/git-diff-whats-the-difference-between-having-and-no-dots).

## See Also

- [Pro Git § 6.1 Git Tools - Revision Selection - Commit Ranges](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges)

Comment: This answer actually explains the difference with a concise text, examples and pictures.  I like it much better than the currently top voted answer which just quotes the unclear documentation. (tl;dr thanks to this answer I actually understand the difference.)

Comment: @Cupcake could you add the meaning off ... in git diff ?

Comment: @Marius if I can spend an hour or so on it someday, then I will, but for now, I'm not going to be adding it any time soon. [This other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/463027/456814) goes into an explanation for `git diff`, though I'm not sure if that answer will be clear for most people. [As I commented on the question above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com/24186641?noredirect=1#comment37336300_462974), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7251477/456814) deals with `git diff` specifically.

Comment: @Marius actually, now that you bring it up, I'll go ahead and link to that other question in my answer, for future readers like yourself.

Comment: Isn't this actually the opposite? dig diff a..b is ALL diffs, or basically the same as git diff a b. Whereas git dif a...b is ONLY changes b has made since branching from a.

Comment: @wejrowski I was confused, so I tried it on a repo that I set up with similar commits. a...b has more commits than a..b. So the diagram is correct.

Comment: At least for git log. For git diff maybe things are reversed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-dif#comment45515553_7256391

Comment: @wejrowski is right.. `git diff A..B` shows **all** commits that they don't have each other; and `git diff A...B` shows **only B has** according to shared ancestor..  _git version 2.18.0_

Comment: Does "git log --right-only master...test" (three dots) equals to "git log master..test" (double dots) ?

Comment: The explanation here is much better IMO
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/2747494. Mixing it with `git log` behaviour doesn't shed more light, but confusion.

Comment: "This is a result of the type of diff we use on GitHub. We use git's three dot diff, which is the difference between the latest commit on the HEAD branch and the last common ancestor commit with the base branch." -- https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/GitHub-pull-requests-showing-invalid-diff-for-already-merged/td-p/3000. So GitHub is using `diff A...B` by default, which is the same as `log A..B`, which means ... I don't quite follow haha. Can you someone help reconcile this SO answer with this explanation from the GitHub discussion link? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Simpler explanation https://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/git_diff_dots.html

Comment: The answer looks very nice - and is plain wrong. It's the opposite, diff .. shows the changes of both branches, while diff ... shows only the changes in the branch in question, counted from the common ancestor. The accepted answer looks less nice, but has the advantage of being right.

Comment: @Eike this answer is correct, and your comment is _also_ correct. `..` and `...` behave differently in `git diff` and `git log`. See the diagram in this answer for clarification - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46345364/14156200

Answer (score 34):

I think the biggest source of confusion about two dots versus three dots is because when used with `git diff` it's **sort of the opposite** of when used with `git log`.

Please see the other answers, the actual documentation, or numerous blog posts for the *exact* details, but I find these simple statements to work well for conveying the right *idea:*

```bash
git log  A..B   # Show me commits only on B.
git log  A...B  # Show me commits only on A or only on B.
git diff A..B   # Show me changes only on A or only on B.
git diff A...B  # Show me changes only on B.
```

Comment: This article explains well enough I believe https://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/git_diff_dots.html

Answer (score 16):

This is a bit confusing = So here is a how it is actually for this flow

```
      A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---F---G main
```

https://github.com/alexcpn/gitdiffs/pull/2/commits
https://github.com/alexcpn/gitdiffs/pull/1/commits

**Git Log Behaviour**

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | > git log --oneline --graph topic...main * 9411a8b (HEAD -> main) G * 3a567aa F * aad429f (topic) C * 6b1eb5a B * d65c129 A | topic D E A B C | main D E F G | In topic and main, but not in both |
| 2 | git log --oneline --graph main...topic * 9411a8b (HEAD -> main) G * 3a567aa F * aad429f (topic) C * 6b1eb5a B * d65c129 A | topic D E A B C | main D E F G | Same as above |
| 3 | git log --oneline --graph topic..main * 9411a8b (HEAD -> main) G * 3a567aa F | topic D E A B C | main D E F G | In main,but not in topic |
| 4 | git log --oneline --graph main..topic * aad429f (topic) C * 6b1eb5a B * d65c129 A | topic D E A B C | main D E F G | In topic, but not in main |

**Git Diff behaviour**

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | git diff topic..main D E -A -B -C +F +G | topic D E A B C | main D E F G | what's in main whats not in main compared to topic |
| 2 | git diff main..topic D E -F -G +A +B +C | topic D E A B C | main D E F G | whats in topic whats not in topic compared to main |
| 3 | git diff main...topic D E (you may get newline here) +A +B +C | topic D E A B C | main D E F G | In topic,but not in main |
| 4 | git diff topic...main D E +F +G | topic D E A B C | main D E F G | In main, but not in topic |

Comment: might want to change 'master' -> 'main' to reduce confusion

Answer (score -1):

The '...' syntax is shorthand for "diff between two branches, starting with the common ancestor". From the [official Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2):

```
git diff master...contrib
```

is equivelent to:

```
$ git merge-base contrib master
36c7dba2c95e6bbb78dfa822519ecfec6e1ca649
$ git diff 36c7db
```