# Git: Find the most recent common ancestor of two branches

Tags: git, git-branch

How to find the most recent common ancestor of two Git branches?

Comment: Define most recent: real world time, number of commits, other metric?

Comment: Relevant (criss-cross merges): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370185/how-do-criss-cross-merges-arise-in-git

Comment: @YakovL I believe no because of branching and because you can set arbitrary commit dates on your commit objects: that date itself is likely not what you want.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心996ICU六四事件 it seems to me that can only be different if before the last common commit in the tree there's a commit that has an older timestamp. Can you provide a less trivial example?

Answer (score 1473, accepted):

You are looking for [`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base). Usage:

```
$ git merge-base branch2 branch3
050dc022f3a65bdc78d97e2b1ac9b595a924c3f2
```

Comment: Note that this finds the most recent common ancestor... which I believe is what the questioner wants, so +1.  Just noting it, in case anyone comes here trying to find the *oldest* common ancestor (as I did) -- for which, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git

Comment: This is probably what he was looking for, but the man page does not guarantee it will be the most recent neither in real time or number of commits: only that it will be one of the best common ancestors.

Comment: I think I'll be using this little snippet a lot: `$(git merge-base HEAD master)`. For example, `git log $(git merge-base HEAD master)..HEAD`

Comment: @funroll: Or the shorthand for that: `git log master...HEAD`

Comment: @lindes would the oldest common ancestor not be the initial commit?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, yes, I suppose that's so... The difficulty in description comes with the fact that git uses a Directed Acyclic Graph, and yet it's often thought of as a tree, which it technically is not.  To be more careful in my wording, I was talking about the case where you want the parent of the first instance of the "branches" diverging... since they may have multiple points where they re-merged and re-split, this is the "oldest" of these, but not truly the oldest ancestor, which is (I think) always the initial commit.

Comment: While this question is strictly about finding a common ancestor of *two* branches, anyone wanting the common ancestor of *three* or more branches should note that they need to pass the `--octopus` flag to get the right result. The obvious-but-wrong `git merge-base branch1 branch2 branch3` will give you a commit, but, as described in the Discussion section in the docs, it *isn't* necessarily a common ancestor of all three branches.

Comment: FYI Run `git log -1 commitHash` to get further information about the commit, for example the commit message.

Answer (score 80):

**`git diff master...feature`**

shows all the new commits of your current (possibly multi-commit) feature branch.

`man git-diff` documents that:

```
git diff A...B
```

is the same as:

```
git diff $(git merge-base A B) B
```

but the `...` is easier to type and remember.

As mentioned [by Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/find-common-ancestor-of-two-git-branches#comment67982133_38436974), the special case of `HEAD` can be omitted. So:

```
git diff master...HEAD
```

is the same as:

```
git diff master...
```

which is enough if the current branch is `feature`.

Finally, remember that order matters! Doing `git diff feature...master` will show changes that are on `master` not on `feature`.

I wish more git commands would support that syntax, but I don't think they do. And some even have different semantics for `...`: [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com)

Comment: Or just `git diff master...` in the special case of diffing to `HEAD`

Comment: the "..." didn't work for me in powershell, funny it worked in git console maybe the repo wasn't complete, git diff $(git merge-base A B) B did and since I am a bit new to git I was a bit sceptical that this might merge the branches :)

Comment: wow. quite amazing. and if the branch you want doesn't exist in your local repo because you never checked it out, you can simply do `git diff origin/branchname...`

Comment: so what is the difference between `git diff branchA..branchB` and `git diff branchA...branchB` ?

Answer (score 53):

As noted in a prior answer, although `git merge-base` works,

```
$ git merge-base myfeature develop
050dc022f3a65bdc78d97e2b1ac9b595a924c3f2
```

If `myfeature` is the current branch, as is common, **you can use `--fork-point`**:

```
$ git merge-base --fork-point develop
050dc022f3a65bdc78d97e2b1ac9b595a924c3f2
```

This argument works only in sufficiently recent versions of git. Unfortunately it doesn't always work, however, and it is not clear why. Please refer to the limitations noted toward the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20966716/832230).

---

For full commit info, consider:

```
$ git log -1 $(git merge-base --fork-point develop)
```

Comment: I have `git version 2.14.1.windows.1`. Running `git merge-base --fork-point branch2` with a branch _(with its own commits)_ that **I know** has forked from the current branch doesn't yield any result, whereas `git merge-base branch1 branch2` correctly shows the fork point. What could be the problem?

Comment: @ADTC Checkout `branch2` and then run `git merge-base --fork-point branch1`.

Comment: @ADTC Use a graphical commit viewer, e.g. `gitk`, etc. to see what the tree looks like. Maybe you will get your answer.

Comment: I see nothing odd about the tree as I view it graphically. I can trace the paths and find the common ancestor which matches the result of `git merge-base branch1 branch2`. But what's odd is that `--fork-point` gives nothing either way. Have you confirmed it works for you as intended?

Comment: @ADTC I now tried it with git 2.14.1 on Linux and it works fine for me. I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: @ADTC If you don't believe that `--fork-point` works in general, try testing it in a new test repo with just a couple of commits. It should work.

Comment: I get the same that @ADTC. The command 'git log -1 $(git merge-base --fork-point anotherBranch)' doesn't show any result using git version 2.16.2.windows.1.

Comment: @masinger I've now updated my answer to note the limitation. FWIW, please refer to the caveats noted toward the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20966716/832230).

Comment: I second that `--fork-point` often fails, especially with `gh pr checkout` and `git-pr` tools.

Comment: To me using --fork-point returns commit that is on forked branch, not common ancestor between branches.

Answer (score 14):

With `gitk` you can view the two branches graphically:

```
gitk branch1 branch2
```

And then it's easy to find the common ancestor in the history of the two branches.

Comment: Not everything can be done visually in every case. There are reasons why things may need to be automated programmatically.

Comment: Not every answer has to cover all possible cases to be useful

Answer (score 0):

find common ancestor of ALL branches

```
git merge-base $(git branch --format "%(refname)")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
git checkout myRep
git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories
git push origin myRep
```