# How to get a list of incoming commits on git push for a new branch in a hook

Tags: git, hook

I'm writing a pre-receive hook to do some validation before accepting commits on the push.
It works fine with existing branches since I use following git command to get a list of
incoming commits:

```
git rev-list $old_sha1..$new_sha1
```

However, above command fails if user pushing a new branch into a shared repository because
old_sha1 is all zeros. So the question is how do I get a list of incoming commits for a 
newly created branch. Doing `git rev-list $new_sha1` does not work since it gives all revisions till the beginning of times. Is there a way to specify something like this:

```
git rev-list $branching_sha1..$new_sha1
```

Comment: Possibly related and possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/git-find-common-ancestor-of-two-branches (`git merge-base`)

Comment: MatrixFrog it's related but not exactly it. I need to figure out a list of commits that are being pushed to central repo inside the server side hook. I was able to kind do it with `git rev-list master..$new_sha1`, but that works only when new branch was done from master. Have not tried with new branch of another branch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
git rev-list $new_sha1 $(git for-each-ref --format '^%(refname:short)' refs/heads/)
```

This uses `git for-each-ref` to print known refs; specifies in `--format` that the short name be output along with a preceding caret; and says with `refs/heads/` to selecting just local heads. You end up running something like this:

```
git rev-list $new_sha1 ^master ^foo ^bar ^baz
```

The caret means “exclude commits reachable from here”. So this will give you all commits that are reachable from `$new_sha1`, but *aren’t* from any of the existing refs.

To handle the new-ref and existing-ref cases at once, you can use bash’s array support:

```
if ! [ $old_sha1 = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ] ; then
    excludes=( ^$old_sha1 )
else
    excludes=( $(git for-each-ref --format '^%(refname:short)' refs/heads/) )
fi

git rev-list $new_sha1 "${excludes[@]}"
```

Comment: Why do you exclude only `$old_sha1`? If the push was a merge, all commits reachable from the merged branch would be processed again, even though the server already knew them.

Comment: The syntax `git rev-list $new_sha1 ^$old_sha1` is exactly equivalent to 
`git rev-list $old_sha1..$new_sha1`, which the OP was already using and satisfied with. I never gave any thought to whether that part is correct.

Comment: That said, I think you are right and I think in that case the answer is to always do the `for-each` song and dance – that is, make the whole code simply this:
`git rev-list $new_sha1 ^$old_sha1 $(git for-each-ref --format '^%(refname:short)' refs/heads/)`
But I’m not sure, so I’m not updating the answer at this time.

Answer (score 3):

More simply, you can use this:

```
git rev-list $new_sha1 --not --all
```

---

It's quite the same principle as in [Aristotle Pagaltzis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531905/2812189), but it just uses `rev-list`'s built-in [options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#_options) (which I guess were added after this question was answered...). 
The `--all` parameter is equivalent to the `for-each-ref` part: it adds all known refs to the command args. The `--not` parameter, *in this particular case,* is like adding the `^` prefix to all refs added by `--all`.
Thus this command will print commits reachable from the new SHA1 except all those reachable from the known (i.e. already pushed) refs.

Answer (score 1):

The following helped in my case. I personally think it's very simple.

```
OLD_REV=$2
NEW_REV=$3

if [ $OLD_REV == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ]; then
    OLD_REV=$(git merge-base master $NEW_REV)
fi;

git diff --name-only $OLD_REV $NEW_REV
```