# Changing git authorship after git push

Tags: git

How do I change the author of my commit after I've already pushed it to the upstream repository

Comment: For an in-depth explanation of why pushing rewritten history can be scary (if anyone may have pulled from the upstream repository) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448973/how-do-you-deal-with-a-public-repository-that-has-already-been-rebased/8449701#8449701

Answer (score 29):

You will have to amend the commit ( `git commit --amend --author="New Author Name <email@address.com>"`) on your local repository and force push- `git push -f` the change ( rewriting history is generally a bad practice once you have pushed upstream ).

Comment: After I do this, instead of "wrongname committed", it now says "rightname authored and wrongname committed" in github

Comment: @Kip This was likely due to having the wrong name configured `user.name` and `user.email` (which is probably the source of the problem in the original mistaken commit).

`git commit --amend --author "New Author Name <email@address.com>"`

The above changes the author, but uses your configured user / email as the committer.

If you want to override the configured user / email, then:

`git -c user.name="New Author Name" -c user.email=email@address.com commit --amend --reset-author`

See the following for more info:

https://gist.github.com/albertodebortoli/b2a6c3ebe82d9c13fe77

Answer (score 16):

## Another complete solution.

In case you got multiple git-push done without realizing that the commits went with a different email account. now you need to change that.
here is the command I have used to transform all my previous commit with a different email to the new email id.

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='yourname'; GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='youremail@example.com'; GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='yourname'; GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='youremail@example.com';" HEAD;
```

Comment: lol at the "Note" about please changing to use your own details.. :)

Comment: A version of this also on GitHub support pages: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/

Comment: Not recommended unless you know what you are doing!

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out here that this changes the entire commit history. It is probably not what you want.