# github Pull Request (PR's ) not showing my github account name

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I've recently worked on contributing to one of the [open source](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/) projects.
Initially I forgot set up commit [email address](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/) on the system i used to work and do commits from.
Because of that all my existing pull requests are **NOT** shown on my github account name.

Is there anyway where I can / owner of those git hub project can attributed PR's to my name?

You can visit this [link](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/pulse) where you'll find **10** commits by **my name** - Madugula Venkataramana ( my github name is **NOT** listed ) and other VenkatsQuest - where my github name is present?

Thanks much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing git authorship after git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480365/changing-git-authorship-after-git-push)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to attach those git commits to your GitHub profile.

The URL for one of the commits is: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/commit/8a73600e9865393c03f248def43ff0b15d8c341e

If you add `.patch` to the end of the URL you get a text based output which shows a bit more detail: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/commit/8a73600e9865393c03f248def43ff0b15d8c341e.patch

```
From 8a73600e9865393c03f248def43ff0b15d8c341e Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Madugula Venkataramana
 <madugulavenkataramana@Venkataramanas-Mac-mini.local>
Date: Sat, 5 Aug 2017 13:58:40 +0530
Subject: [PATCH] Added the Missing MethodBindinPluginBootstrap file
```

There you can see that your committer email address (which is how GitHub associates commits with accounts) is `madugulavenkataramana@Venkataramanas-Mac-mini.local`.

If you could add that email address to your GitHub profile it would work, but there's no way to register the domain `Venkataramanas-Mac-mini.local`.

Comment: Interestingly my GitHub Profile is already having my email address( madugula.venkataramana@gmail.com ) added to it.Still i had this issue.