# Generate a diff of all changes made in a branch?

Tags: tortoisegit

I am not very experienced with Git but I think this is a TortoiseGit-specific version of: [Git diff between current branch and master but not including unmerged master commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808892/git-diff-between-current-branch-and-master-but-not-including-unmerged-master-com)

When working in a feature branch, I would like to see:

1. all changes I made to a file since branching
2. all files I've changed in the branch

But specifically, how I can do this in TortoiseGit rather than on cmd-line?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Log
2. Select both branches

   1. To make this easier you can click on the "Branch selector" in the upper left
   2. Select both branches there, on "OK" select "branchA branchB"
3. On the log you see now both branches, select both branches (the latest commit of each branch)
4. Open the contect menu and select "Compare"
5. Open Diff options and select "Use common ancestor"

Comment: @mr-boy Does this answer your question? if not please add a comment.