# Fork file(s) into different folder

Tags: git

I have a repo where files are organized by users:

```
-user1
--folder1
---file1
---file2
--folder2
-user2
--folder3
```

etc.

Now i want to make a fork of some work `user1` has done.
I forked the repo, added a `me` user, and a folder `mywork` which will contain, initially, a copy of `folder1`, so

```
-user1
--folder1
---file1
---file2
...
-me
--mywork
---copyoffile1
---copyoffile2
```

Once I'm done, if all goeas well, this fork will be merged into the main repo, with my work folder separate from `user1`'s, but, ideally, 'linked'. Users of the repository will need to be able to see the 2 versions maintaned by 2 users, in the same main branch.

Is there a way in git to 'fork' `folder1` into `mywork` so changes to `folder1` are preserved?

Comment: err.. this is git, not mercurial right? just creating a different git branch should be enough. you don't have to physically copy the file.

Comment: I second the above. This is not how git is supposed to be worked with. Not saying it can't be done, but it will be painful.

Comment: Users of the repository need to be able to eventually see the 2 versions maintaned by 2 users, in the main branch.

Comment: @Mau you can diff 2 [commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368590/show-diff-between-commits) or [branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808892/git-diff-between-current-branch-and-master-but-not-including-unmerged-master-com). if you insists then you are trying to turn a screw using a hammer given you have a hammer at hand.

Comment: What exactly was the difficulty? Make a copy of the directory and commit it.

Comment: The diffidulty is dealing with people who don't try to understand the problem.

Comment: @Mau put a bounty, see if your question actually make sense given git `branch` should be good enough. you could clone a single repository on **two** different folders and have them pointing on different branches. you can then manually compare stuff, by hand, grep, what have you. this is git, not tfvcs or svn - when in rome, do as romans do, if you don't want to then move to greek or persia whichever that works.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I gather there is no specific process for this in GIT.

The use case of porting the changes from the other user's folder can be met with a diff/merge of the 2 folders.

Comment: Tbh that sounds like you are re-inventing pull requests.