# Show local commits when branch name contains slash

Tags: git, branch, local, commit, git-log

I have a git branch containing slash in its name, e.g. `my/branch`
Now when I want to see my local commits (the commits which are local only and not pushed to the remote) by running

> git log origin/my/branch..HEAD

git brings the following error message:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/my/branch..--HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>
> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git  [...] -- [...]'

I don't quite understand how to use this hint by git. How can I view my local commits in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when `my/branch` does not exist on `origin` (to be precise: if your local copy does not known `origin/my/branch`).

Call `git branch -r` to see if `origin/my/branch` is known on your local repository.  If not try `get fetch origin`.

If this all does not help post the result of `git branch -a` and  `git remote`.

Comment: Hi @Jens. Looks like I run into precisely this case. The remote or origin doesn't contain my branch, but is merged with master. So my guess was that git should be able to compare my branch with origin master and provide the commits which aren't on the origin.

Answer (score 0):

> when I want to see my *local* commits

"*local*" means: not on `origin` (the reference to the remote repo) yet.

A simple `git log` (without `origin`) is enough

```
git log my/branch
```

For getting only the commits you don't have pushed, [assuming you have branched from `master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20966716/6309):

```
git log $(git merge-base --fork-point master my/branch) my/branch
```

(that is by default the same as `git log my/branch..HEAD`)

For your first push:

```
git push -u origin my/branch
```

Comment: Hi @VonC. In this case I get the whole history of commits, including the one I haven't pushed yet.

Comment: @superM OK. I have updated the answer to list only unpushed commits.

Comment: thanks for the update. I tried the command you suggested, but still getting all the history with
git log $(git merge-base --fork-point master my/branch) my/branch

Comment: @superM should work though (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com). Check first if `git merge-base --fork-point master my/branch` returns the right commit.