# git reset --soft - does it go back to git checkout point or to the last git merge point?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout, git-reset

I think what I am looking for is the oldest shared ancestor of two branches, or something like that, this question seems to touch on it:
[Finding a branch point with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git)

But instead of the diagram in the OP, this is more what I am looking at:

```
-- I -- I -- I -- I -- I -- I -- I  (integration branch) 
          \         \          /
           \         \        /
             F -- F -- F -- F  (feature branch)
```

My question is - if we checkout a feature branch from integration and make some changes and some commits, and then we update/merge with integration a few times as we go. Aka, commit commit, merge with integration, commit commit, merge with integration, etc. If we then do a `git reset --soft <integration>`, is that going to reset it to the commit on integration when `git checkout` was used, or will it simply reset it to the point where the last `git merge` with integration occurred?

The goal is so that I can make my feature into one big commit. If the `git reset --soft` only goes back as far as the last git merge with integration, then my feature might have 100s of commits, which is no bueno, and I will need another technique.

Comment: [`git reset --soft`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset---soft) moves the current branch where you tell it to move it. It does not do any search or decision by itself. You are looking for [`git merge-base --fork-point`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#git-merge-base---fork-point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you are merging feature back to `integration`, you are moving `integration` HEAD (which now reference the new merge commit)

You need to mark `integration` *before* doing your `feature` branch and your merges in order to get back to it.

One possible marker would be `origin/integration`: that last time you fetch `integration`).

Another one is `git merge-base --fork-point` (based on `reflog`, so unreliable) or some diff between `git rev-list --first-parent` of both branches.

In any case, your `git reset --soft` would have to use that marker, *not* the local integration branch.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, I guess `git reset --soft <thing>`, finds <thing> in the current branch and undos all commits back until that point. So it's just a matter of finding the right <thing> to go back to.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman Yes, that is the idea. `git reset --soft` removes commits, but keep the final content intact (work tree and index). But you still need *where* to go back to.

Comment: Hmm yeah, isn't there some way to find out the first commit on a new branch? I just need to rewind back to that basically. Integration branch could get rebased or messed up, so I could potentially handle that by only looking at my feature branch and nothing else.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman the only ways I know of are listed in the post you reference in your question, and that I allude to in my answer: merge-base of rev-list.

Comment: Yeah I googled some more and all signs point to those two, thanks

Comment: I think using `merge-base --fork-point` should work and looking at the git docs I don't think it *only* depends on the reflog, it uses other info too or something. But if you could explain how diffing `rev-list --first-parent` is supposed to work, that would be nice because that's less intutive.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman It just looks for the first common commit between two histories. The --first-parent makes sure you are only selecting commits from the current branch, not commits from a merge branch (second parent)

Comment: I wonder if `git merge-base --fork-point` just does a diff on `git rev-list --first-parent` internally.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman Not exactly: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20966716/6309. Wait... this answer is not selected?

Comment: i didn't know whether to give you credit or @torek, I just flipped a coin TBH, I can reflip the coin as needed lulz

Comment: I will contact the StackOverflow mafia to get at least one more upvote for this answer

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman Which ever answer seems clearer to you is the right one. I just forgot about this question, and didn't realized that since I answered it, torek came along.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use `git reset --soft`, but there's something else you must do—or rather, *not* do—first.

> The goal is so that I can make my feature into one big commit.

In that case, make sure you *don't* start with:

```
-- o -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- IM   <-- integration
          \         \          /
           \         \        /
            F1 -- F2 - FM - F4   <-- feature
```

Note that I have replaced the individual letters here so that I can talk about particular commits.  The two most interesting commits, as far as Git itself is concerned, are `F4`, which is the tip commit of the branch named `feature`, and `IM`, which is the tip commit of the branch named `integration`.

The commit labeled `FM` is not a problem, even though it *is* a merge commit.  **The commit labeled `IM` *is* a problem.**  That's because this commit is reachable from the tip of `integration`.  For (much) more on the concept of reachability in general, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  Whenever commit `IM` itself is reachable by starting at the commit to which `integration` points, and working backwards (leftwards), so are all commits that commit `IM` itself reaches.  Commit `IM` leads back to both commit `E` (not a problem) and `F4` (problem!).

If you *eliminate* commit `IM`, so that you have:

```
-- o -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E   <-- integration
          \         \
           \         \
            F1 -- F2 - FM - F4   <-- feature
```

you can now `git checkout feature` and run `git reset --soft integration`, resulting in this:

```
-- o -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E   <-- feature (HEAD), integration
          \         \
           \         \
            F1 -- F2 - FM - F4   [abandoned, but remembered as feature@{1}]
```

Your *index* and *work-tree* are unchanged from when you had commit `F4` checked out, though, so you can now run `git commit` to turn the current index into a *new* commit.  The name `feature` will now point to the new commit:

```
                              F   <-- feature (HEAD)
                             /
-- o -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E   <-- integration
          \         \
           \         \
            F1 -- F2 - FM - F4   [feature@{1}]
```

The *snapshot* for new commit `F` will match that for commit `F4`:

```
git diff feature@{1} feature
```

will print nothing at all.  But the *parent* of new commit `F` is existing commit `E`.  (Commit `F` also has a new author and committer and corresponding "now" time stamps, which also distinguish it from `F4`.)

Comment: Thanks for this - I will have to read about reachability, but I guess on the face of it I don't quite see why commit `IM` is a problem?

Comment: If you add a new commit atop commit `IM`, the new commit will point back to `IM`, so that `git log` will first show commit `F`, then `IM`, then—in some order—all of `A-B-C-D` and `F1-F2-FM-F4`. The reason is that Git traverses *both* chains (in backwards order, but otherwise simultaneously).