# Find common ancestor of more than two branches

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

[Find common ancestor of two git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/find-common-ancestor-of-two-branches) - this question explains how to show a common ancestor for two branches.

```
git merge-base branch1 branch2
```

However, I want to see a common ancestor of three or more branches. At first, I thought this would work.

```
git merge-base branch1 branch2 branch3 branch4
```

But it doesn't actually return the common ancestor of all the branches; as noted in [the docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html)

> Given three commits *A*, *B* and *C*, `git merge-base A B C` will compute the merge base between *A* and a hypothetical commit *M*, which is a merge between *B* and *C*

which isn't what I want.

How do you find a common ancestor commit of more than two branches?

Comment: `git merge-base --octopus branch1 branch2 branch3 branch4` should work . The documentation isn't extremely explicit on the actual effects of the `--octopus` flag, but it does mention that it's equivalent to `git show-branch --merge-base ...`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work

```
git show-branch --merge-base branch1 branch2 branch3 branch4
```

Thanks to the comment of user twalberg, the following command is the equivalent to show-branch

```
git merge-base --octopus branch1 branch2 branch3 bracnh4
```