# How to find origin of a branch in git?

Tags: git, branch

Say if my project contains two masters (master and master_ios) and I want to see what the origin of a feature branch is (by origin, i mean the branch the feature branch is based off), how would I accomplish this in git?

Comment: [Find common ancestor of two branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/find-common-ancestor-of-two-branches) solves your task

Comment: The question is not asking to find a common ancestor. Is it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
git remote show origin
```

shows remote and local branches with tracking info.

Comment: this command only tells me, that my branch is tracked but not its origin. So how is this the answer to the question?

Comment: This command asks for a password if not authorized. Not suitable if you just want to get the remote URL.

Comment: @user8434768 In local branch section it shows the remote branch of your local branchs.

Answer (score 19):

For people who just want to see all the remote urls

`git remote -v`

Answer (score 14):

Git does not track what branch a commit was created on and does not track where a branch was branched off from. There is no information in git that you can use answer that question.

source: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Knowing-from-which-branch-the-current-branch-was-created-from/qaq-p/570135

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the Graph available on the [Repository menu](https://gitlab.com/ondrejfoltyn/nunti/-/network/master) :

See screenshot

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

```
cat .git/config
```

will give you where you based your branch