# Atlassian Stash says that the second pull request merged remotely

Tags: git, merge, pull-request, bitbucket-server

There were 2 different pull requests: A and B.
When the A pull request has been merged into master in Stash, Stash shows that pull request B has been **merged** **remotely** (but it didn't!). Somehow it worked automatically. There are no hooks.

I tried running:

```
git log --merges
```

But I can't see the merge commit for B.

Can you please help?

The git tree is as follows:

```
*   c8372e0 (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'master' of http://...
|\
| *   b091241 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge pull request #193 in ...
| |\
| | * 629fb1f (origin/feature/A Fix
...
| | * e9042fb (origin/feature/B) 
| | *   d84a03c Merge branch 'master' into feature/B
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer:

Branch A was created not from a master but from branch B.
When A's pull request is merged, B is merged as well automatically.

**The reason:** They have the same parent

You can check it with git command to [find a common ancestor of two commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/find-common-ancestor-of-two-branches), e.g.:

```
git merge-base -a 629fb1f e9042fb
```