# How to find the common ancestor of two branches before a merge commit in git?

Tags: git

**Background**

I'm trying to write a script that will simplify my backport process using git.

The general process for fixing a bug in the current version goes something like this:

1. Branch from `master` to a bug fix branch, e.g. `bugfix/abc`
2. Make all the commits to fix the bug on `bugfix/abc`
3. Merge `bugfix/abc` to `master` (without fast-forward merges)

Now when I want to backport the fix to version 1 for example (branch `v1`) I do:

1. Create a new branch from `bugfix/abc`, e.g. `bugfix/def`
2. Then manually find the commit on `master` that was before the merge commit, e.g. `f4d399238f`
3. Now I use rebase: `$ git rebase --onto v1 f4d399238f bugfix/def`

This works great (after working out that I had to use the commit before the merge for the upstream).

**Question**

How do I find the common ancestor of two branches *before* a merge commit? (for step 2 of the backport process).

**Tried**

1. `git merge-base bugfix/abc master`

   - Since the merge has already been done this just returns the commit at the head of `bugfix/abc`
2. Combining the result of #1 to get the child of this commit using `git log`

   - I tried following [How do I find the next commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git) using various combinations of `--reverse`, `--ancestry-path` and `--children` but I never got what I expected.

**Update**

The key difference between this question and [Find common ancestor of two branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/find-common-ancestor-of-two-branches) is that the two branches have already been merged. As I mentioned the *best commit* is returned as the head of the branch that was merged. I need the common ancestor **before the merge commit**.

Assume that the branches after the bug has been fixed and merged into master look like:

```
A---B v1
     \
      C---D---F---H master
           \     /
            E---G bugfix/abc
```

Running `$ git merge-base master bugfix/abc` will return *G* but I need to get *D* (or even *F* would do for the purpose of using `rebase --onto`).

Once I get *D* I would then run:

```
$ git branch bugfix/def bugfix/abc
$ git rebase --onto v1 D bugfix/def
$ git checkout v1
$ git merge bugfix/def
```

To end up with the desired result of:

```
      E'---G' bugfix/def
     /      \
A---B--------I v1
     \
      C---D---F---H master
           \     /
            E---G bugfix/abc
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find common ancestor of two branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/find-common-ancestor-of-two-branches)

Comment: The key difference here is that I need the commit before the merge commit. That question specifically asks for the most recent but I essentially need the second most recent.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I find the common ancestor of two branches before a merge commit? (for step 2 of the backport process).

There are several options to use:

#### git merge-base

[`git merge-base`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) is the command you are looking for

> *git merge-base* finds best common ancestor(s) between two commits to use in a three-way merge. One common ancestor is *better* than another common ancestor if the latter is an ancestor of the former. A common ancestor that does not have any better common ancestor is a *best common ancestor*, i.e. a *merge base*. Note that there can be more than one merge base for a pair of commits.

#### Manually find it from the log

`git log --decorate --graph --oneline --all`

This will display the fork points in the log so you can track the commit id of the branching.

Comment: Thanks but I already explained why `git merge-base` didn't work. If you know how to get it to work can you please elaborate? I have made an update to make this clearer. Also the manual step is not what I want. The purpose is to write a script to do this, I can already do it manually that is the easy part.

Answer (score 0):

For the case that I have shown I found a reasonable solution:

```
git rev-list --first-parent master | gawk -v bugfix=bugfix/abc '{
    commit = $1
    branchCmd = "git branch --contains \"" commit "\" \"" bugfix "\""
    if (branchCmd | getline) {
        print commit
        exit
    }
}'
```

This will print `D`.

It turns out that this fails if `master` was ever merged into `bugfix/abc` as shown here:

```
      E'---G'---h' bugfix/def
     /           \
A---B-------------J v1
     \
      C---D---F-------I master
           \   \     /
            E---G---H bugfix/abc
```

In this case it will print `F` but that is still not what we want.

If only there was some option for the `branch --contains` to limit the parents, such as `--first-parent` like there is for `rev-list`...

A workaround was to modify the script to the following:

```
git rev-list --first-parent master | gawk -v bugfix=bugfix/abc '{
    commit = $1
    branchCmd = "git branch --contains \"" commit "\" \"" bugfix "\""
    if (branchCmd | getline) {
        timestampCmd = "git show -s --format=%ct \"" commit "\""
        if (timestampCmd | getline timestamp) {
            revlistCmd = "git rev-list --first-parent --max-age=" timestamp " \"" bugfix "\""
            while (revlistCmd | getline line) {
                if (commit == line) {
                    print commit
                    exit
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

The idea here is that we take each possible result and check whether that is reachable from `bugfix/abc` but only following the first parent. The `--max-age` means we only go back as far as necessary. If it is not reachable then it must have been a merge from `master` to `bugfix/abc`. If it is then we print the commit hash and exit.