# how do you merge master and next branch in github

Tags: git, github, opentsdb

There is a master branch:

https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb

and a next branch:

https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/tree/next

I need to clone master, download the next branch, merge them and build them:

I've tried this:

```
git clone https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb.git --depth=1  -b next

cd opentsdb/

git fetch origin master:master --depth=1

git merge -s ours master
```

When I'm trying to build the final code, I get this error:

```
javac: file not found: src/query/TagVFilter.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
make[1]: *** [.javac-stamp] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/app/data.3/opentsdb/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do you merge master and next branch in github?

Comment: but which files are you missing? you're outputing the Java error which could be unrelated to the git commands. Do you get any errors white running the git commands? What happens on fetch and merge?

Comment: @bitoiu, I don't get any errors on fetch and merge. I am even sure, I am doing this right. Can you help? I need to merge next and master locally and build it.

Comment: Try to run `javac` on both unmerged branches. Does it succeed?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, it is not javac. I am not able to merge master and next locally. I need help cloning master and then next then merging them.

Comment: And what is that strategy `ours`? Could it blindly merge files and make them non-compileable?

Comment: it means if any conflicts appear, it will take the changes from the local branch, yes blindly!

Comment: GitHub shows lots of changes... https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/compare/next

Comment: @NickVolynkin, how would I merge master and next branch locally and build. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1471980 none yet. Trying to do it myself.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

I would suggest taking the branch `next` and merge `master` into it, manually resolving conflicts.

```
git clone https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb.git
cd opentsdb
git checkout -b next origin/next
git checkout master
git merge next
```

Now there are some conflicts in, it should be, 3 files: `NEWS`, `configure.ac`, `src/core/AggregationIterator.java`. You have to [resolve them manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/fix-merge-conflicts-in-git).

It appears that `AggregationIterator.java` gets merged automatically.

#### Long essay on research of this particular repository and possible merges.

The following command

```
git diff --stat next > diff.txt
```

Gives us:

> 157 files changed, 5924 insertions(+), 22414 deletions(-)

So the branches should probably be merged manually.

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate master..next > master_next.txt
```

Output is 196 lines. That means that `next` has gone 196 commits ahead of `master` since branching. However,

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate next_master > next_master.txt
```

is just 7 lines:

```
* 45e575a (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Improve query performance in the AggregationIterator by calling .hasNext() on the downsampler instead of letting it build a giant exception string that we're just tossing in the bit bucket.
* 248fee6 (tag: v2.1.0) Release version 2.1.0
* bb061c7 Merge branch 'next'
* 7129df4 (origin/maintenance) Remove links to the old Google code repo in the third party includes.
* 791c9e3 Cleanup the Config class a bit. Make sure to close the conig file after opening and add more unit tests.
* 2b5b5f3 Add unit tests for config directory fix Move null check to top of config directory parsing so that it will take care of Windows systems as well
* 11ac8f3 Fixed issue throwing a null exception when a config directory is null.
```

The [merge-base of two commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/find-common-ancestor-of-two-branches) is `dcf516f96ed10ce0b95b1e62847fbead723b87e1`.

```
git diff dcf516f96ed10ce0b95b1e62847fbead723b87e1

 NEWS                              | 16 ++++++++++++++--
 configure.ac                      |  2 +-
 src/core/AggregationIterator.java |  9 ++-------
 3 files changed, 17 insertions(+), 10 deletions(-)
```

So, you only have three files that were changed in `master` since their common ancestor with `next`. Probably hotfixes. You've got very little work to do.

Comment: there is no automated way of updating this, using git?

Comment: I am sorry. I meant to say, I am not familiar with merging next with master.

Comment: ok, before executing checkout or merge, dont I have to clone it first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80323/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-user1471980).