# How can I get a diff of a file since the last time I merged?

Tags: git, merge, git-diff, merge-conflict-resolution

I am attempting to merge master into a dev branch with a lot of changes and ran into some merge conflicts.

**How can I get a diff of what changed in the file since the last *shared* commit in my dev branch using the git console commands?**

So lets say my branches have the following last 5 commits:

```
master:
  abb
  abc
  abd
  abe
  abf

dev:
  abb
  cda
  abc
  abd
  cdb (merge master to dev at abd)
  cdc
```

And I would now like the equivalent of:

```
git diff abd..abf filename.ext
```

But, because I am in the middle of a merge with conflicts, i'm not sure how to find those two commit hashes without looking through the log's of both master and dev.

Comment: Maybe you can use a tool like SourceTree on Windows or SmartGit on Linux could help you to find the commit hashes. Having a visual representation of the branches will maybe clarify your situation and they can let you diff through different commits pretty easily.

Comment: @lordjohncena Thanks for the info. I have updated the question to explicitly state I would like a console based solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git diff has a special form of the '...' operator, so the following will work also.

```
git diff dev...master filename.ext
```

see git help diff

Answer (score 2):

Writing up this question helped me realize how to search for the answer which is this:

```
git diff $(git merge-base master dev) master filename.ext
```

**Explanation:**

```
git merge-base master dev
```

Will find the [most recent common ancestor between the two branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549155/1991100)

```
git diff <base commit> master
```

Will show a diff between the commit specified and the newest commit within the master branch.

**Note:**

If you want to be sure you are looking at the latest, use `origin/master` instead to diff between the remote.