# Git Merge not receiving some changes from another branch

Tags: git

I am working on a project with a coworker, and we are both making changes to separate tools on the app. We typically do not have problems, but something strange is happening now.

Every day we pull from master, periodically add ., commit, and push changes throughout the day. At the end of the day, we merge branches using...

```
git merge origin/otherPersonsBranch
```

... we then both add ., commit, and push again before we leave.

Yesterday, we noticed that there is at least one file where some changes aren't merging. We are not yet aware of any others.

We are not receiving merge conflicts, and usually :quit the vmeditor when that pops up.

When merging or pulling, we are both getting 'Already up-to-date'.

Maybe we set up the branches incorrectly at the start? I don't know. What am I 'git'ing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: May I advice something like [git extensions](http://gitextensions.github.io/)?

Comment: Maybe the file was never committed in the first place.  When you make changes to the file and then type `git diff` do you see any changes?

Comment: If I make a change to the file in question on my branch, save, and do git diff, yes I do see the changes displayed to me in the terminal.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I will consider git extensions in the future, but I just prefer using the Terminal right now, because I am new-ish to the dev world and I feel like I can learn better using the Terminal. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @Alex028502 Same thing on coworkers branch, despite the two files being 'different' between each others branch

Comment: `gitk --all` is a great tool.  it only does the stuff that would be extremely painlful from the terminal.  It gives you a really good picture of how all the branches fit together, and comes packages with git

Comment: also have you  tried `git fetch`? I'm not sure if `git pull` will update your copy of your coworker's branch.  It might just update your branch.

Comment: When I git fetch --all, my list of branches does not change. Afterwards, I tried to merge with the branch with desired changes, again in vain.

Comment: I just noticed, when I git checkout to the otherPersonsBranch, the file in question I get 
'error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
xx/xx/fileInQuestion.js
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches'
So I committed, and did git checkout to that branch. The file I see now after checkout is the file I had, without the desired changes.

Comment: I switched branches to otherPersonsBranch, and observed that the desired changes are present. Then I added, committed, and pushed. I switched back to myBranch and did git merge on that branch again, still the change is not coming in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

> I just noticed, when I git checkout to the otherPersonsBranch, the file in question I get:
>
> ```
> error: Your local changes to the following files would be
> overwritten by checkout:
>    xx/xx/fileInQuestion.js
>  Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches
> ```

is definitely important.  It *is* possible to run `git merge` with uncommitted changes in the work-tree, but I *strongly* recommend against that.  (The main problem is that if the merge goes wrong, it can be very difficult to back out of it.  If you have committed everything, it is easy to back out of it.)

In any case, once you do have everything committed, to see what a merge will do, first find the *merge base*.  See, e.g., [Find the most recent common ancestor of two Git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549146/1256452) or many of my recent answers.  The merge will compare the merge base to each of the two branch tip commits.  You can do this same thing yourself, using `git diff`—see the special syntax in that same answer, or:

> Yesterday, we noticed that there is at least one file where some changes aren't merging.

Git doesn't compare the two branch *tips* to each other.  Running `git merge $other` compares the base to *your* branch tip:

```
git diff --find-renames $base HEAD   # see what we did
```

and again to *their* branch tip:

```
git diff --find-renames $base $other # see what they did
```

and then combines those two sets of changes.  So the chosen merge base is critical to this process, as are the contents of the two tips.  (Any commits in between are quite literally irrelevant, except in terms of their role in locating the merge base commit.)

(When you have uncommitted changes, the first `git diff` is in effect against your index, rather than your `HEAD` commit.  Actually, this is always true, it's just that if everything is committed, `HEAD` and your index match, by definition.  Meanwhile, the low level merge process, which runs after the two diffs have done the appropriate file-matching, attempts to preserve un-indexed work-tree changes as well; this is where things get really messy.)

Comment: This is great, I did not know I could do that. I can see the differences between mine and her branch right now. and it seems just that one js file.

How can I prevent this from happening in the future? I am not even sure what I did wrong. Could I have missed a step by mistake while trying to push my changes?

Comment: It's hard to tell from here. Note that you can run `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` (mnemonic: help from A DOG, All Decorate Oneline Graph) to have Git show you, graphically, the branch-y structure of the commits, from which you can *see* the merge base. (Well, sometimes it's clear, and sometimes it's very unclear; the one place where GUIs can help a lot is here, showing the graph. Mostly I stick with the command line when I can, though.)

Comment: Okay. I will go ahead and do what you and Ron said above, install the gui, and see how that goes. Maybe I will learn something. To work around the problem I had, I simply copied the missing code from my coworkers branch. It wasn't much. I just wish I knew what I did to cause it to happen. In the future I will be more consciencious about what git commands I am running in the Terminal. In the meantime I will just accept this answer (and then go take a GitHub course...)
Thanks guys!

Comment: Note that if you can use `gitk` you don't need a full GUI (well, `gitk` is sort of gui-ish, but I mostly just use it for faster browsing when dealing with particularly messy repositories).