# Retrieving the Git rebase base commit hash

Tags: git

I'm looking for a way to determine what `git rebase <branchname>` does to get the commit hash that it should be the base. I'm going to use the hash to determine what actually to build in a monorepo.

Heres an example

```
develop --1--2------5--6-->
              \
feature        3--4------->
```

If from `feature`, I do `git rebase develop`, Git figures out that I want to base my changes in commit 3 onto 6. It rewinds `feature` to 2, plays 5 and 6 from `develop` then 3 and 4 from `feature`.

How would I find commit 2's hash in this example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: Find the most recent common ancestor of two branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/git-find-the-most-recent-common-ancestor-of-two-branches)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at git merge-base

```
$ git merge-base develop feature
```