# Is there a way to find the branching commit from the merge commit

Tags: git

I'm looking for a git command (or set of commands) that can return the 'branching' commit from the merge commit.

For example, suppose I have the following tree:

```
A______B______C_______D________E________F
        \_________G___________/
```

Given the merge commit E, the command should return B.

Comment: Would this do the trick? `git merge-base E^1 E^2` ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yeah exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/git-find-the-most-recent-common-ancestor-of-two-branches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `git merge-base`, it tells you what the most recent common ancestor there is for two commits.

To get the common ancestor for your `E` commit in your example, you would execute this command:

```
git merge-base E^1 E^2
```

where `E` would be whatever references the commit in question, like:

- HEAD if you've currently checked out that commit
- A branch name
- A tag name
- The hash of that commit