# how to get git log -p to show changes in merge commits

Tags: git

I have a branch with a function definition missing but the function is still being used causing a crash. The function definition must have been deleted during a merge. I have done 'git log -p' and searched for the function definition and I can see it being defined but couldn't find it being deleted later on. This leads me to believe that 'git log -p' doesn't show merge changes? How can I get this functionality?

Comment: you can use `git show <merge commit>` or `git log -c`. from `git log` man page: `-c With this option, diff output for a merge commit shows the differences from each of the parents to the merge result simultaneously instead of showing pairwise diff between a parent and the result one at a time. Furthermore, it lists only files which were modified from all parents.`

Comment: With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), a simple `git log -m` should be enough, as it will show patches as well. See [my updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63605966/6309).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> This leads me to believe that 'git log -p' doesn't show merge changes? How can I get this functionality?

You are correct: by default, `git log -p` shows you the merge commit, but does not even *attempt* to show a diff for it.

As [odradek wrote in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43138569/how-to-get-git-log-p-to-show-changes-in-merge-commits#comment73362380_43138569), adding the `-c` option will make `git log` show *combined diffs*.  You may also use `--cc` (note two dashes for `--cc`, vs one dash for `-c`) which also shows a combined diff, or `-m`, which effectively *splits* the merge for diff purposes, and shows one diff per parent, against that parent.

These same three options can be used with `git show`.  For whatever reason, though, `git show` *defaults* to `--cc` while `git log` defaults to nothing at all.

The difference between the three options is clear only with some merges, and it's a bit tricky to show them.  We *can*, however, say one thing pretty clearly: **any combined diff shows only files that differ from all parents.**  That is, *both `git show -c` and `git show --cc` trim what's shown* to try to be helpful.  (The `--cc` form may trim more than `-c`, depending on what there is that can be shown.  I do not have a handy example of this, though.)

For example, consider [commit `3e5c63943d35be1804d302c0393affc4916c3dc3` in the Git repository for Git](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e5c63943d35be1804d302c0393affc4916c3dc3).  This is a merge (with parents `c13c783...` and `20690b2...`, and if we run two *separate* `git diff` commands, we can see that, as compared to its *first* parent, only two files change:

```
$ git diff --name-status 3e5c639^1 3e5c639
M       builtin/remote.c
M       t/t5505-remote.sh
```

but as compared to its *second* parent, *many* files (including those same two) change:

```
$ git diff --name-status 3e5c639^2 3e5c639 | expand
M       .gitignore
M       .mailmap
M       Documentation/Makefile
A       Documentation/RelNotes/2.12.0.txt
M       Documentation/SubmittingPatches
A       Documentation/asciidoctor-extensions.rb
M       Documentation/blame-options.txt
M       Documentation/cat-texi.perl
M       Documentation/config.txt
M       Documentation/diff-config.txt
[snipped here - but the same two files do appear in the 339-entry list]
```

If I run `git show --cc` on this, I get no diff listing at all; if I run `git show -c` on it, I get a diff listing for `builtin/remote.c` and for `t/t5505-remote.sh`.

If I run `git show -m` on this, I get instead two separate `git diff` listings.  *Neither* is a "combined diff".  The first starts with:

```
commit 3e5c63943d35be1804d302c0393affc4916c3dc3 (from
 c13c783c9d3d7d3eff937b7bf3642d2a7fe32644)
```

and shows just the first two files.  The second starts with:

```
commit 3e5c63943d35be1804d302c0393affc4916c3dc3 (from
 20690b213975ad3e9b1bc851f434d818bd2d1de9)
```

and shows all 339 files.

Using `-m` is the Really Big Hammer, but you are left with a lot of sorting to do through a lot of pieces.  Using `--cc` or `-c` is usually sufficient.

(Something else that may help, when looking for this sort of change with `git log -p`, is to add `--full-history` to make sure that `git log` follows *both* branches down each merge.  This is only required if you are doing history simplification by adding `-- <path>` options.)

Answer (score 6):

> This leads me to believe that '`git log -p`' doesn't show merge changes?

It does, with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021): "[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aac006aa99fd94ac1665d6daa31b9e289914bfe7/Documentation/git-log.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> learned a new `--diff-merges=<how>` option.

And with git 2.33 (Q3 2021), `git log -m` will imply `-p` (patch) (see at the end of this answer).

See [commit af04d8f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af04d8f1a5a38373fba762071824bc85da7cc050), [commit 1d24509](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d24509b7b865115836982267a5e54b2f7d77c42), [commit e58142a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e58142add40e0db354eaed9554d1b0c871e23f7d), [commit 8efd2ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8efd2efc32c41c7dcc2bf86a11fa89377f1c8d94), [commit b5ffa9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5ffa9ec10a3b82a1530d6f7628bd3ef9e8dd037), [commit 388091f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/388091fe4d9e06475f491c195e84e1996aad3f42), [commit 5071c75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5071c7531692f53cdfec43542f1cbaee573fd2be), [commit a6d19ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a6d19ecc6b7715b50b0dced7e3d2923a8797df64), [commit 5733b20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5733b20f41ac0fecdacdf34a11acef2d03fac829), [commit 8c0ba52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c0ba528bc3c61f4582bf68d3f0cc2a72f5f3792), [commit 255a4da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/255a4dacc59f4f4f62cc61743f40a078b4b38647), [commit 3d2b5f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d2b5f2f496b9868f982b614f9c2232efa7505df), [commit a6e66af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a6e66af923d54f44bc7d0a404109e900a6a1cb60), [commit d9b1bc6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9b1bc6d13f6581f1e91f21d20b50b7312c60e62), [commit 1a2c4d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a2c4d80501c50fbe96cc0be096273703a5c0d16), [commit 6fc944d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6fc944d8956bf75bf2e52a871c02b71b4f9dfcba), [commit ec315c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec315c66bb73e26542b7b3de8abaffa310c4380e), [commit 14c14b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14c14b44e47bc8c420e5161abc8fe283121f3e31), [commit e121b4b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e121b4b822765336cd4710ec9f8aed77d25de3fe), [commit 0c627f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c627f5d3cbcb7d85219d9a4cfc195f7d4230b3d), [commit 3291eea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3291eea3104e1a1aa64181671da3f9551ec3d59f), [commit 3b6c17b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b6c17b5c0bd126e3c712f5de909a033d99f1e3a), [commit 09322b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09322b1da92fd32204c8b4b07cf12decccfe47f3), [commit 564a4fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/564a4fc8471b41fc05bda16e4bbb02a99b515cbf), [commit 4f54544](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f54544d736e286538ebef0d3120c164f80f04c1), [commit 7acf0d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7acf0d06f54043b3b79d5d388ed1c8fb66e2db5a), [commit 18f0947](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18f09473bf8685a1f8db254cff915d4c31e86406), [commit a37eec6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a37eec6333db6f38edd21e74812d6c5f215b6e6c), [commit 3d4fd94](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d4fd9436337d1688e7e2c2b2da4f7b7e3e8591e), [commit 027c478](https://github.com/git/git/commit/027c4783d73bbaff0a3c494b886cd8fa20ba8372), [commit 299a663](https://github.com/git/git/commit/299a66344065583162518cd8b65e2b91132eb1ac), [commit 891e417](https://github.com/git/git/commit/891e417cbc70495efca4f1333a8bb3c587fb69cb) (21 Dec 2020) by [Sergey Organov (`sorganov`)](https://github.com/sorganov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit aac006a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aac006aa99fd94ac1665d6daa31b9e289914bfe7), 05 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`diff-merges`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c0ba528bc3c61f4582bf68d3f0cc2a72f5f3792): implement new values for `--diff-merges`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sergey Organov</sup>

> We first implement new options as exact synonyms for their original counterparts, to get all the infrastructure right, and keep functional improvements for later commits.
>
> The following values are implemented:
>
> ```
> --diff-merges=            old equivalent 
> first|first-parent      = --first-parent (only format implications)
> sep|separate            = -m
> comb|combined           = -c
> dense| dense-combined   = `--cc`
> ```

> ### [`diff-merges`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5071c7531692f53cdfec43542f1cbaee573fd2be): add old mnemonic counterparts to `--diff-merges`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sergey Organov</sup>
>
> This adds `--diff-merges={m|c|cc}` values that match mnemonics of old options, for those who are used to them.
>
> Note that, say, `--diff-meres=cc` behaves differently than `--cc`, as the latter implies `-p` and therefore enables diffs for all the commits, while the former enables output of diffs for merge commits only.

> ### [`diff-merges`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/388091fe4d9e06475f491c195e84e1996aad3f42): add '`--diff-merges=1`' as synonym for '`first-parent`'
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sergey Organov</sup>

> As we now have `--diff-merges={m|c|cc}`, add `--diff-merges=1` as synonym for --diff-merges=first-parent, to have shorter mnemonics for it as well.

> ### [`doc/git-show`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d24509b7b865115836982267a5e54b2f7d77c42): include --diff-merges description
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sergey Organov</sup>

> Move description of `--diff-merges` option from `git-log.txt` to `diff-options.txt` so that it is included in the [`git-show`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1d24509b7b865115836982267a5e54b2f7d77c42/Documentation/git-show.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show))</sup> help.

`diff-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1d24509b7b865115836982267a5e54b2f7d77c42/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L36-L86):

> ### `--diff-merges=(off|none|first-parent|1|separate|m|combined|c|dense-combined|cc)`
>
> ### `--no-diff-merges`
>
> Specify diff format to be used for merge commits. Default is
> {diff-merges-default} unless `--first-parent` is in use, in which case
> `first-parent` is the default.
>
> ### `--diff-merges=(off|none):`
>
> ### `--no-diff-merges:`
>
> Disable output of diffs for merge commits. Useful to override
> implied value.
>
> ### `--diff-merges=first-parent:`
>
> ### `--diff-merges=1:`
>
> This option makes merge commits show the full diff with
> respect to the first parent only.
>
> ### `--diff-merges=separate:`
>
> ### `--diff-merges=m:`
>
> ### `-m:`
>
> This makes merge commits show the full diff with respect to
> each of the parents.
> Separate log entry and diff is generated
> for each parent.
> `-m` doesn't produce any output without `-p`.
>
> ### `--diff-merges=combined:`
>
> ### `--diff-merges=c:`
>
> ### `-c:`
>
> With this option, diff output for a merge commit shows the
> differences from each of the parents to the merge result
> simultaneously instead of showing pairwise diff between a
> parent and the result one at a time.
>
> Furthermore, it lists
> only files which were modified from all parents.
>
> `-c` implies `-p`.
>
> ### `--diff-merges=dense-combined:`
>
> ### `--diff-merges=cc:`
>
> ### `--cc:`
>
> With this option the output produced by
> `--diff-merges=combined` is further compressed by omitting
> uninteresting hunks whose contents in the parents have only
> two variants and the merge result picks one of them without
> modification.  `--cc` implies `-p`.
>
> ### `--combined-all-paths`
>
> This flag causes combined diffs (used for merge commits) to
> list the name of the file from all parents.  It thus only has
> effect when `--diff-merges=[dense-]combined` is in use, and
> is likely only useful if filename changes are detected (i.e.
> when either rename or copy detection have been requested).
> endif::git-log[]

`git log` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1d24509b7b865115836982267a5e54b2f7d77c42/Documentation/git-log.txt#L131):

> :diff-merges-default: `off`

`git show` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1d24509b7b865115836982267a5e54b2f7d77c42/Documentation/git-show.txt#L48-L51):

> ### `DIFF FORMATTING`
>
> The options below can be used to change the way `git show` generates
> diff output.

`git show` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1d24509b7b865115836982267a5e54b2f7d77c42/Documentation/git-show.txt#L54):

> :diff-merges-default: `dense-combined`

---

This is based on the work from Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), formally documented:

See [commit 5fbb4bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5fbb4bc1910f76b344fcb88df2544701b6030435), [commit 9a6d515](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a6d515fc38abc36a94228f2b96813e1b07c0059), [commit 6cea104](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cea104b2c0266d61fbce7e9ba485dc6d13c0c8f), [commit 6f2e02a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f2e02aeb004a2ecd6aec1732f4abeaf88fba4b9), [commit 9ab89a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ab89a2439064720cc790c4477b8e981832c43f5), [commit 6fae74b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6fae74b418da05a80897487805c833fd0b253df3), [commit eed5332](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eed5332a13ef15391039e5e953462201978058ec) (29 Jul 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit eca8c62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eca8c62a50e033ce6a4f4e065bb507ca3d98e75c), 17 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`doc/git-log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5fbb4bc1910f76b344fcb88df2544701b6030435): clarify handling of merge commit diffs
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> It can be surprising that `git-log` doesn't show any diff for merge commits by default.
> Arguably "`--cc`" would be a reasonable default, but it's very expensive (which is why we turn it on for "[`git show`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5fbb4bc1910f76b344fcb88df2544701b6030435/Documentation/git-show.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show))</sup> but not for "`git log`").
>
> Let's at least document the current behavior, including the recent "`--first-parent implies -m`" case

`git log` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5fbb4bc1910f76b344fcb88df2544701b6030435/Documentation/git-log.txt#L120-L126):

> Note that unless one of `-c`, `--cc`, or `-m` is given, merge commits
> will never show a diff, even if a diff format like `--patch` is
> selected, nor will they match search options like `-S`.
>
> The exception is
> when `--first-parent` is in use, in which merges are treated like normal
> single-parent commits (this can be overridden by providing a
> combined-diff option or with `--no-diff-merges`).

---

And you also have:

> To countermand the implicit "`-m`" option when the "`--first-parent`" option is used with "[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a555b514cd47f59b43f571eaff6b8cd7c01f0d11/Documentation/git-log.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> , we added the "`--[no-]diff-merges`" option in the `jk/log-fp-implies-m` topic.
>
> To leave the door open to allow the "`--diff-merges`" option to take values that instructs how patches for merge commits should be computed (e.g. "`cc`"? "`-p` against first parent?"), redefine "`--diff-merges`" to take non-optional value, and implement "`off`" that means the same thing as "`--no-diff-merges`".

See [commit 298889d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/298889d3e2053cf903b01fbac902cbfb210109ea), [commit 405a2fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/405a2fdf998d42469634efeff8461f221bb9398b), [commit 6501580](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6501580ff85fc13e64fe02288dd514d3d898a781) (06 Aug 2020) by [Sergey Organov (`sorganov`)](https://github.com/sorganov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a555b51](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a555b514cd47f59b43f571eaff6b8cd7c01f0d11), 17 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`doc/git-log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/405a2fdf998d42469634efeff8461f221bb9398b): describe `--diff-merges=off`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sergey Organov</sup>

`git log` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/405a2fdf998d42469634efeff8461f221bb9398b/Documentation/git-log.txt#L155-L159):

> ### `--diff-merges=off`
>
> ### `--no-diff-merges`
>
> Disable output of diffs for merge commits (default).
> Useful to override `-m`, `-c`, or `--cc`.

---

With Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), "[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/59bb0aa93e6edaca44b2a5488fc915d468bae46f/Documentation/git-log.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> learned `--diff-merges=<style>` option, with an associated configuration variable `log.diffMerges`.

See [commit 364bc11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/364bc11fe5711fe7fbb98abf376168a207e7a448), [commit 17c13e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17c13e60fd799336b28d320dcba06fe1ef06e01d), [commit 38fc4db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38fc4dbbc2f110192752a3b2c99abb745f0494bf), [commit 26a0f58](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26a0f58da84a7da11f9175144c9a926e7b376349), [commit 4320815](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4320815eb9a002b4ee64f70dda9b1c1e019f4894) (13 Apr 2021) by [Sergey Organov (`sorganov`)](https://github.com/sorganov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 59bb0aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59bb0aa93e6edaca44b2a5488fc915d468bae46f), 30 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`diff-merges`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17c13e60fd799336b28d320dcba06fe1ef06e01d): introduce log.diffMerges config variable
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sergey Organov</sup>

> New `log.diffMerges` configuration variable sets the format that `--diff-merges=on` will be using.
> The default is "separate".
>
> Added documentation for `log.diffMerges`.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/17c13e60fd799336b28d320dcba06fe1ef06e01d/Documentation/config/log.txt#L27-L31):

> ### `log.diffMerges`
>
> Set default diff format to be used for merge commits. See
> `--diff-merges` in [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for details.
> Defaults to `separate`.

---

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), the "`-m`" option in "[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8e444e66df45ee5bbe84af0d884c6625627219f3/Documentation/git-log.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> -m that does not specify which format, if any, of diff is desired did not have any visible effect; it now implies some form of diff (by default "--patch") is produced.

See [commit f5bfcc8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5bfcc823ba242a46e20fb6f71c9fbf7ebb222fe), [commit fd16a39](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd16a39944ce2f2967ed015379f5bd05bac639bb), [commit 1e20a40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e20a407fe28b4bdba3b973b26b0b60ff6b6c97d), [commit 23f6d40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23f6d40dd3e7aad72c7706bb75f77a6c73b69b56), [commit 19b2517](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19b2517f95a0a908a8ada7417cf0717299e7e1aa), [commit e0b1642](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0b16421b17fffa2544eebfcb570fdb766fd0bc4), [commit 3ae7fe2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ae7fe2b0f8528305bc871738dd12cde23024556), [commit faf16d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/faf16d4e97ed45e8e570a8d1d568449e948284f0), [commit 48229c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48229c193d2e6e728d3243bacea2f1e1490ced8a), [commit 7a55fa0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a55fa0e0bb88e2bf721bc65cc55cd6b435a8373) (21 May 2021) by [Sergey Organov (`sorganov`)](https://github.com/sorganov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8e444e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e444e66df45ee5bbe84af0d884c6625627219f3), 14 Jun 2021)</sup>

> ### [`diff-merges`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5bfcc823ba242a46e20fb6f71c9fbf7ebb222fe): let "`-m`" imply "`-p`"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sergey Organov</sup>

> Fix long standing inconsistency between `-c`/`--cc` that do imply `-p` on one side, and `-m` that did not imply `-p` on the other side.
>
> Change corresponding test accordingly, as "`log -m`" output should now match one from "`log -m -p`", rather than from just "`log`".
>
> Change documentation accordingly.
>
> NOTES:
>
> After this patch
>
> ```
> git log -m
> ```
>
> produces diffs without need to provide `-p` as well, that improves both consistency and usability.
> It gets even more useful if one sets "`log.diffMerges`" configuration variable to "`first-parent`" to force `-m` produce usual diff with respect to first parent only.
>
> This patch, however, does not change behavior when specific diff format is explicitly provided on the command-line, so that commands like
>
> ```
> git log -m --raw
> git log -m --stat
> ```
>
> are not affected, nor does it change commands where specific diff format is active by default, such as:
>
> ```
> git diff-tree -m
> ```
>
> It's also worth to be noticed that exact historical semantics of -m is still provided by --diff-merges=separate.

`diff-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5bfcc823ba242a46e20fb6f71c9fbf7ebb222fe/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L52):

> the default format. The default format could be changed using

`diff-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5bfcc823ba242a46e20fb6f71c9fbf7ebb222fe/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L54):

> `-m` implies `-p`.

`diff-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5bfcc823ba242a46e20fb6f71c9fbf7ebb222fe/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L64-L65):

> This is the format that `-m` produced historically.

---

Note: With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), earlier "[`git log -m`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4c90d8908ac0c7ec9cd8d2caee7a1a0394636612/Documentation/git-log.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> was changed to always produce patch output, which would break existing scripts, which has been reverted.

See [commit 6a38e33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a38e33331560c3e84123c567f95de72d1cfa506) (05 Aug 2021) by [Jonathan Nieder (`artagnon`)](https://github.com/artagnon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4c90d89](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c90d8908ac0c7ec9cd8d2caee7a1a0394636612), 11 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`Revert 'diff-merges`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a38e33331560c3e84123c567f95de72d1cfa506): let "-m" imply "-p"'
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>

> This reverts [commit f5bfcc8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5bfcc823ba242a46e20fb6f71c9fbf7ebb222fe) (`diff-merges`: let , 2021-05-21, Git v2.33.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e444e66df45ee5bbe84af0d884c6625627219f3) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/670b81a890388c60b7032a4f5b879f2ece8c4558)), which made "[`git log -m`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a38e33331560c3e84123c567f95de72d1cfa506/Documentation/git-log.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup>  imply `--patch` by default.
> The logic was that "`-m`", which makes diff generation for merges perform a diff against each parent, has no use unless I am viewing the diff, so we could save the user some typing by turning on display of the resulting diff automatically.
> That wasn't expected to adversely affect scripts because scripts would either be using a command like "[`git diff-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a38e33331560c3e84123c567f95de72d1cfa506/Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree))</sup> that already emits diffs by default or would be combining `-m` with a diff generation option such as `--name-status`.
> By saving typing for interactive use without adversely affecting scripts in the wild, it would be a pure improvement.
>
> The problem is that although diff generation options are only relevant for the displayed diff, a script author can imagine them affecting path limiting.
> For example, I might run
>
> ```
> git log -w --format=%H -- README
> ```
>
> hoping to list commits that edited README, excluding whitespace-only changes.
> In fact, a whitespace-only change is not TREESAME so the use of -w here has no effect (since we don't apply these diff generation flags to the `diff_options` struct `rev_info`::pruning used for this purpose), but the documentation suggests that it should work
>
> ```
> Suppose you specified foo as the <paths>. We shall call
> commits that modify foo !TREESAME, and the rest TREESAME. (In
> a diff filtered for foo, they look different and equal,
> respectively.)
> ```
>
> and a script author who has not tested whitespace-only changes wouldn't notice.
>
> Similarly, a script author could include
>
> ```
> git log -m --first-parent --format=%H -- README
> ```
>
> to filter the first-parent history for commits that modified README.
> The `-m` is a no-op but it reflects the script author's intent.
> For example, until [1e20a40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e20a407fe28b4bdba3b973b26b0b60ff6b6c97d) (stash list: stop passing , 2021-05-21, Git v2.33.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e444e66df45ee5bbe84af0d884c6625627219f3) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/670b81a890388c60b7032a4f5b879f2ece8c4558)) (stash list: stop passing "-m" to "`git log`", 2021-05-21), "[`git stash list`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a38e33331560c3e84123c567f95de72d1cfa506/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L70)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-listltlog-optionsgt))</sup> did this.
>
> As a result, we can't safely change "`-m`" to imply "`-p`" without fear of breaking such scripts.
> Restore the previous behavior.
>
> Noticed because Rust's src/bootstrap/bootstrap.py made use of this same construct: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/87513.
> That script has been updated to omit the unnecessary "-m" option, but we can expect other scripts in the wild to have similar expectations.

`diff-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a38e33331560c3e84123c567f95de72d1cfa506/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L52-L53):

> `-m` will produce the output only if `-p`
> is given as well.

Comment: Note: gitk has been fixed with Git 2.34: https://github.com/git/git/commit/e8332242b74634ce34a37b0896b86b59848cf8cd