# How to see merged changes?

Tags: git, merge, changeset

I ran `git pull origin master`. After this I run `git log --patch`.

I see the my changes, but I see no changes which were merged:

```
commit XXX (HEAD -> XXX)
Merge: XXX XXX
Author: Victor Porton <XXX>
Date:   Mon Mar 5 16:38:00 2018 +0200

    Merge branch 'master' of ssh://XXX:/XXX into XXX
```

^^^ no patch here :-(

How to see merged changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `diff` the changes from the merge commit to it's parent commit on the master branch. If this is your merge commit:

```
commit 02b5edc439b9774c749b1740d7a511dd08cc1ee9 (origin/master)
Merge: 1521b45 5016eda
Author: <author@foobar.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 5 13:34:26 2018 +0000

    Merge branch 'foo' into 'master'
```

You could do this:

```
git diff 02b5edc 1521b45
```

Or, as described in the [answer linked to in the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986518/git-show-of-a-merge-commit):

```
git diff 02b5edc 02b5edc^
```

This is obviously more elegant, because you don't have to figure out the parent commit yourself.