# Github Desktop warned of merge conflict but did not allow me to manually resolve

Tags: git, github-desktop

Normally, when Github desktop indicates 1 or more merge conflicts, it does not auto resolve and will show the file(s) with conflicts and require manually editing that file to resolve the conflict. Once in a while, it will indicate a conflict, but it "auto merges." I don't know what was done or which file had the conflict.

I've had bad experiences with this before where an auto merge resulted in broken code, so I'm concerned here. How to do find the conflict?

Comment: Get a better git UI. GitKraken and SourceTree are leagues ahead of stock git tooling in VS and GitHub's own branded frontend.

Comment: I use SourceTree for repos on bitbucket. The reason for using Github desktop was exactly because it was simple and light weight. Anything else I needed could be done via command line. The question here is, could this auto merge cause an issue and is there a way now for me to go back and review it (either by cmd line or another tool?)

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the issue persists with the latest version of GitHub Desktop ([currently 3.1.2](https://desktop.github.com/release-notes/), Oct. 2022). It includes a more recent Git 2.35.2 which can help fix issues with merge.

Second, check if a [`git show HEAD -m`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69826174/6309) help checking out what was automatically merged.