# Git command to check which files changes after merge

Tags: git, merge

Which terminal command can i use to check which files were changed after a fast forward merge WHITHOUT the squash option ?
I need it for a CI so i can't execute one command and check by myself for a specific commit SHA and use it after to check the changes.

Lets take an example:

I create `develop` branch from `master`, i make my changes (5 commits) and i merge `develop` into `master` without squash option. At this point i want to execute a command that return me all changed files (comparing before and after the merge)

**I can't use a specific commit hash in my command since it's for my CI and I don't know in advance what the hash will be**

I've tried :

- `git diff --name-only HEAD~` but it compare the HEAD with the
  precedent commit and in case of fast forward without squash it will
  not necessarily be the commit before the merge.
- `git diff --name-only HEAD@{1}` as @eftshift0 suggest but it is not
  working in CI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "git show" the diffs for a merge commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986518/how-to-git-show-the-diffs-for-a-merge-commit)

Comment: In order for this to be possible, from the log alone, you need to make sure you have a merge commit. In the simple scenario you described, if `develop` was merged into `master` with fast-forward, you *can't* determine what changed on `master` from its history alone. If you use `--no-ff` to force a merge commit then you can diff `master` with it's first parent like in [eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75402019/184546).

Comment: What's the hard part? At the very least show us the command you did use and explain what's wrong with the result.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~
```

Assuming you did not go anywhere after the merge (and that the merge is finished).

In cases when there is a fast-forward, you can do this right after merging:

```
git diff --name-status HEAD@{1}
```

That should work for non-ff scenarios *too* but it's a little flaky overall (if you move around after merging, the reference would point to a different commit).

Comment: I think it would help to mention that there should be a merge commit. (I commented on the question about this.)

Comment: Great point. Let me add a tip in my answer (cause it's possible to do it with ff)

Comment: "That should work for non-ff scenarios" Nonsensical. Delete "non"?

Comment: Oh... now I'm wondering if I misunderstood the question. Regarding OP's statement, "I need it for a CI so i can't execute one command and check by myself", I was under the impression that the thing doing the merge isn't necessarily the same thing doing this check. I think the reflog would only work if the "thing" running the script, just did the merge?

Comment: @matt should I add a _too_ at the end? _That should work for non-ff scenarios **too**_ (which is what I meant... it works for both ff and non-ff).

Comment: Aha! Yes, now I see

Comment: thanks @eftshift0 `git diff --name-status HEAD@{1}` is working localy but not in CI. I suppose that HEAD@{1] refer to the previous HEAD and since in CI we have a new git environment it doesn't have access to it.

Comment: That will work wherever you are doing the merge.... if you want to run it in a place that is _not_ where the merge is taking place, then that won't work.