# Git - diff a range but ignore merges

Tags: git, merge, diff, git-diff

So here's the situation:

There's a big task with over 30 commits that I'm reviewing. Already went through one cycle of review and fixes and now I'd like to review the **fixes only**. The Problems is, meanwhile around 200-something commits were merged from master to the feature branch:

```
         code review
              ↓
    B---D---F---H---J---L---M---N---O feature
   ↗                   ↗
--A---C---E---G---I---K master
```

How do I go about diffing the changes of the `H` to `O` range to `F`, while ignoring what came in from the merge?

Rebasing is troublesome due to many conflicts.

Comment: You can create a temporary branch on `O`, check it out then run `git rebase --onto J L`. This way the new branch skips the `L` commit and `git diff F` includes only the changes introduced by commits `H, J, M, N, O` (I assume here that `L` is the merge commit).

Comment: - Chcekout on F, create new branch there, cherry pick changes H,J, L(unleess it's  a merge?), M,N,O. Git diff F on that new branch

Comment: I updated the answer: rebasing causes many conflicts, so I'd rather try other options without having to rebase

Comment: If there were many conflicts in L, there could  be no good answer. Review separately F->J, the conflict resolution in L, L->O and overall change as K->O

Comment: @max630 is there any special way to review the conflict resolution?

Comment: except `git show`, you could try something from https://stackoverflow.com/q/5072693/2303202

Comment: Thank you very much Max!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `L` is the merge commit, you can create a temporary branch on `O`, check it out then run `git rebase --onto J L`. This way the new branch skips the `L` commit and `git diff F` includes only the changes introduced by commits `H, J, M, N, O`. Make sure you don't have uncommitted changes before starting. The existing branches are not affected.

The commands are:

```
git checkout -b temp O
git rebase --onto J L
git diff F
```

When you end the review you can run:

```
git checkout feature
git branch -D temp
```

to checkout `feature` again and remove the temporary branch.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I forgot to mention, I did already try rebasing but there are so many conflicts, I'd rather try other options without having to rebase

Comment: You get conflicts on rebasing because the changes in the commits after the merge (`M`, `N`, `O`) operate on lines changed by the merge. You cannot skip the merge commit in this situation.

Comment: I think the best way in this case is to review the changes introduced by commits `H` and `J` (`git diff F J`) then review the changes introduced by the commits `M`, `N` and `O` (`git diff L O`).

Comment: Thanks axiac. I think I'm going to go with [running.t's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530781/git-diff-a-range-but-ignore-merges/49532170?noredirect=1#comment86070269_49530781) of checking out a branch from `F`, and then cherry-picking all the rest bar the merge commit

Comment: Cherry-picking doesn't change anything. If skipping `L` produces conflicts, you'll get them no matter how you attempt to apply `M`, `N` and `O`. The work Git does to perform `git cherry-pick` and `git rebase` is the same.

Comment: Unfortunately you are right! I guess reviewing commit-by-commit is the only way to go in this particular case. I just scheduled a dev meeting to discuss rebasing instead of merges, and other workflow matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mention that rebasing generates a lot of conflicts.  That says to me that the code in `M` through `O` is likely dependent on the merge, and reviewing it without the merge may be a fruitless endeavor.  That said, there are some things you could try:

One option is to check out feature, create a temporary branch, and on the temporary branch revert `L`.  This would create a new commit `~L` which you could compare to `F`.  If the rebase attempt generates conflicts, this may also generate conflicts; but at least you'd only have a single resolution step.

Another option is to review in two steps.  First compare `F` to `J`, then compare `L` to `O`.  It means looking at two patches, but if that's two modest-sized patches instead of one gigantic one consisting mostly of "noise", it could still be a win.