# How to list local commits difference in git

Tags: git, version-control

I have a remote repository cloned locally, and over time, I have added local commits to that cloned repository.

Now, whenever I do `git status`, I see **Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by xx commits** message.

**Q:** How do I list only commits made locally, so that I can examine these commits into more detail, and eventually merge some of them into upstream?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do it by specifying the range to the `log` command:

```
git log origin/master..master
```

Use your branch name instead of master, of course.

You can read more for example here: [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-git-commit-ranges)

Also, read `man gitrevisions`.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. Quite often I forget which tool is right for which job in git, given the abundance of commands. :)

Comment: is there a way to find *all* differences between beginning of the branch and now? It seems to me that this command only lists commits since last commit that exists in local but not in remote repo..