# In git, what's the difference between A..B and A...B?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between “..” and “…” in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-git-commit-ranges)

I see on various tutorials two different syntaxes for commit ranges :

```
git log A..B
git log A...B
```

What's exactly the difference between both ?

Comment: Yup, added answer, as I couldn't delete question anymore...

Comment: In such cases just wait till the question is closed. The link to the duplicate will then be inserted at the top of the question and it will be left as a possible google signpost or deleted.

Comment: @pmr will do. At least, it did sparkle an executive summary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is: include all commits up to B, excluding all up to and including A. The second: include all commits up to be, excluding all up to and including common ancestor(s). See `git help revisions`, section **SPECIFYING RANGES**.

Comment: +1 for executive summary of the said linked duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Ouch.

Is a duplicate of [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974).

Why didn't it show up in my various searchs remains mysterious.