# Git fetch but no diff between local and remote

Tags: git, git-diff, git-fetch

I have some issue with `git diff` command. I know `HEAD` in the remote and on the local don't point to the same commit. Remote has received some more commits. But when I run `git fetch` and then `git diff HEAD...origin`, or `git diff HEAD...origin/master`, or `git log -p HEAD..origin`, I have no diff shown. Someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong operator to define the diff endpoints (confer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/463027/1761499)). You can use `git diff origin/master` to see a diff between your currently checked out commit (HEAD) and origin/master, or you can see a list of commits with `git log --all HEAD..origin/master`.

Using "origin" as a commit descriptor as you tried will produce an error (it is not a commit'ish or tree'ish reference), or it might be implicitly resolved, which you should avoid to get the exact results you want.