# Get the difference between two branches in Git

Tags: git

I did following (I simplified this comparing to a reality):

- created a branch **Branch1**, switched to it
- added file **File1** and modified existing file **File2** and commited this
- figured out that I don't need **File1**, removed it and commited this

So, the actual difference between **original branch** and **Branch1** is only modification of **File2**.

I want to get this actual difference between branches and put in **Branch2**. Generally speaking, I want to get rid of not necessary history of adding/removing **File1**.

Comment: try `...` between revisions, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/463027/654952

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Let's assume that you started on the branch `master`. Then you can do:

```
git diff master Branch1 > ../patchfile
git checkout Branch2    
git apply ../patchfile
```

Alternatively, if your goal is to rewrite history, then you could use an [interactive rebase](https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase) to squash commits.

Comment: I don't think "interactive rebase" can solve his problem. With rebase you can pick which commits are you want, but in his case, he has 2 commits but neither of these 2 is he want.

Comment: @sevenever If, in the interactive rebase, he squashes together the two commits, the addition and removal of  **File1** will disappear and only the modification of **File2** will remain. That would achieve what he wants.

Comment: As an addendum, if you're using a setup where the diff is automatically colored, add `--no-color` to `diff` to ensure the resulting patch is still valid. If you need to include binary files, add `--binary`.

Answer (score 13):

This is a simple git diff

```
git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2
```

Where SHA1/2 are the hashes of the 2 commits at the top of each branch.

Or you can do

```
git diff --name-only develop...
```

To compare your branch against the `develop` branch

Comment: This gives me only the names of changed files (which is nice). However, I need more than just names to create Branch2

Comment: I think more correct solution would be "git diff SHA1 SHA2 >some.patch" and after on new branch "patch -p1 < some.patch"

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Allows me to restore all my changes as local changes on a base branch so I can see them all at once in my IDE rather than losing the changes every time I commit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do an interactive rebase on `HEAD~2` and squash the last two commits together. Assuming that you want to keep the history as is in `Branch1` and simplify it in `Branch2`, do the following (current branch `Branch1`):

```
git checkout -b Branch2
git rebase -i 'HEAD~2'
```

An editor will open up, showing something like

```
pick 1b58da0 Added File1, changed File2
pick d3f4f51 Delete File1
```

and many explanatory comments how rebasing works. Change the last commit to a `squash` and close the editor.

```
pick 1b58da0 Added File1, changed File2
squash d3f4f51 Delete File1
```

A new editor will open up where you can specify the new commit message. It would probably now just read

> Changed File2

Close it and you're done, both commits are squashed together on `Branch2` and `Branch1` retains your original history. Note that if you don't need to retain the original history, you can just skip checking out `Branch2` and work directly on `Branch1`. Only do that if you haven't published your last two commits on `Branch1` already.