# Github: comparing across forks?

Tags: github, compare, diff

**Short version**

When I compare two forks on Github, it does not compare the latest states, but the current state of the base fork with the last common commit (or am I wrong?); so how can I compare the latest states/heads on Github?

**Longer version**

I am trying to [compare two repositories](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/#comparing-across-forks) on Github.

It does not seem to compare the latest states of both repository. Instead, it compares:

- the base fork as it was when both repositories where identical (last common commit?)

with

- the head fork as it is now.

You can see this in the [Github's fork comparison example](https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/master...gjtorikian:master), it says there are no changes between those two repositories, but there are now very different.

How can I compare the latest states/heads on Github?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/master...gjtorikian:master

> `github:master` is up to date with all commits from `gjtorikian:master`.
>   Try [switching the base](https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/gjtorikian:master...github:master) for your comparison.

It means that all commits from [gjtorikian/liguist](https://github.com/gjtorikian/linguist/) are part of [`github/linguist`](https://github.com/github/linguist).

The reverse is not true:
https://github.com/gjtorikian/linguist/compare/master...github:master

That would give all (1866) commits from [`github/linguist`](https://github.com/github/linguist) which are not part of [`gjtorikian/linkguist`](https://github.com/gjtorikian/linguist/).

This is triple-dot '`...`' diff between the common ancestor of two branches and the second branch (see "[What are the differences between double-dot “`..`” and triple-dot “`…`” in Git diff commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6309)"):

[image: git diff double and triple dots]

In the first case `github/linguist:master...gjtorikian/linguist:master`, the common ancestor and `gjtorikian/linguist:master` are the same! O commits.

In the second case `gjtorikian/linguist:master...github/linguist:master`, `github/linguist:master` has 1866 commits since the common ancestor (here, since `gjtorikian/linguist:master`).

Comment: Ah ok! So one must know which repo is the newest before comparing?

Comment: @arthur.sw yes, or you can switch in case of empty result: if the switch is not empty, you know which one is newer, and which one is older. If the switch is empty, both are identical.

Comment: Thanks! I did not pay attention to this switch before :-)

Comment: @arthur.sw as you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6309 (similar to log with http://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/6309), the '...' diff has different result depending on the order.

Answer (score 23):

As a side note, the compare of forks can be reached from the compare page.

Say your project is Zipios:

https://github.com/Zipios/Zipios

What you want to do is add the `.../compare` to that URL:

https://github.com/Zipios/Zipios/compare

On that page, you can select two branches but if you look closely, at the top there is a link that says: **compare across forks**.

Once you clicked on that link, it shows you two extra dropdowns with your main branch and the list of forks.

What I have yet to discover is how to go from the main page of a project to the Compare page. Maybe someone could shed light on that part?

---

From @somerandomdev49:

> *To go to the compare page, go to the "Pull Requests" tab and click the "Create Pull Request" button.*

Comment: To got to the compare page, got to the "Pull Requests" tab and click the "Create Pull Request" button

Comment: @somerandomdev49 Oh! That is worth its own answer. That's the actual solution. Of course, clicking on "New Pull Request" (not "Create ...") is not intuitive...