# Number of Commits between two Commitishes

Tags: git, github

How can I find the number of commits between two commitishes in `git`?

Additionally, is there some way that I could do the same with any project on GitHub (using the UI, not the API)?

Comment: If you have two commits you have their revision number no?  Subtract the two?  I may be oversimplifying or not understanding the question.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas in `git`, a commitish isn't necessarily a commit ID. Also, even if you have the commit IDs, in git, commit IDs are hashes (ff3823ac, 554fbae3, etc.).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Before I give you an answer, consider this commit graph:

```
        o -----------
       /             \
... - A - o - o - o - B
       \         /
        o ----- o
```

Each `o` represents a commit, as do `A` and `B` (they're just letters to let us talk about *specific* commits).  How many commits are there between commits `A` and `B`?

That said, in more linear cases, just use `git rev-list --count A..B` and then decide what you mean by "between" (does it include B and exclude A? that's how `git rev-list --count` will behave).  In branchy cases like this, you'll get all the commits down all the branches; add `--first-parent`, for instance, to follow just the "main line".

(You also mentioned "commitish", suggesting that we might have annotated tags.  That won't affect the output from `git rev-list`, which only counts specific commits.)

---

Edit: Since `git rev-list --count A..B` includes commit `B` (while omitting commit `A`), and you want to exclude both end-points, you need to subtract one.  In modern shells you can do this with shell arithmetic:

```
count=$(($(git rev-list --count A..B) - 1))
```

For instance:

```
$ x=$(($(git rev-list --count HEAD~3..HEAD) - 1))
$ echo $x
2
```

(this particular repo has a very linear graph structure, so there are no branches here and there are two commits "between" the tip and three-behind-the-tip).  Note, however, that this will produce -1 if `A` and `B` identify the *same* commit:

```
$ x=$(($(git rev-list --count HEAD..HEAD) - 1))
$ echo $x
-1
```

so you might want to check that first:

```
count=$(git rev-list --count $start..$end)
if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
    ... possible error: start and end are the same commit ...
else
    count=$((count - 1))
fi
```

Comment: What do you do if you want to get the total across all of the branches added up? Also, by between, I was thinking of "exclusive" (excludes A & B).

Comment: The `git rev-list` command (try it without `--count`) walks the graph, printing the SHA-1 of every commit you select.  The `A..B` notation means "select every commit reachable starting from B and working back through all parent commits, but then exclude every commit reachable by starting from A and working back", so if you want all of them, you're in great shape, because that's what you get.  Meanwhile, since `rev-list` includes `A` itself, subtract one.

Comment: could you put the comment in your answer along with a one liner that also subtracts one (perhaps pipe the result into `| xargs expr -1 +`) and then I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Done.  Also I fixed the remark about which commit is included in the revisions walked (it's `B`, not `A`, that gets counted).

Comment: Does this guarantee that `A` is a parent of `B`? What if `A` is in another branch, not merged yet... or a descendant of `B`?

Answer (score 52):

```
$ git log 375a1..58b20 --pretty=oneline | wc -l
```

Specify your start commit followed by your end commit, and then count the lines.  That should be the count of commits between those two commit ranges.  Use the `--pretty=oneline` formatting so that each commit takes up a single line.

Note that using two dots (`375a1..58b20`) is different than using three dots (`375a1...58b20`); see [What are the differences between double-dot “..” and triple-dot “…” in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641) for more information about this and to figure out which one you want to use.

As for the GUI in GitHub, I don't know of a way to accomplish this same task.  But that should be trivial, as the above is the possible way to do it directly using Git and Bash.

Comment: It requires two dots or three dots between the commit id's in the above command?

Comment: This was probably just copied over from here: http://gal.steinitz.com/blog/2013/07/27/git-tips-count-number-of-commits-between-two-commits/

Comment: it's worth reading the comments to @kghbln's comment link for details about order of first and second commits, and an option that doesn't rely on `wc` (namely `git rev-list [newer] ^[older] --count`)

Comment: With two dots, I get nothing. With three dots, it works.

Answer (score 7):

### Another ONE LINER

```
git rev-list newer ^older --pretty=oneline --count
```

##### Use revision numbers or SHAs:

```
git rev-list db8fb95e6256bd52a668bae82d8b5a73152869fa ^1aeae117c58c173fee9cb3550297498142887aa5 --pretty=oneline --count
```

- [newer] and [older] can be SHA’s, branches or tags.
- **Important:** If you have a complicated git graph you should read @torek 's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31998123/3689364).
- Credit goes to @matt wilkie in his comment and the [original source](http://gal.steinitz.com/blog/2013/07/27/git-tips-count-number-of-commits-between-two-commits/).

Answer (score 0):

commit ranges can fail on a broken repo:

```
$ git rev-list --count b00aa8ded74..master
error: Could not read 29026cc404895cc9f9afa55c4e2d53b7a4a5a319
fatal: revision walk setup failed

$ git log --oneline b00aa8ded74..master | wc -l
error: Could not read 29026cc404895cc9f9afa55c4e2d53b7a4a5a319
fatal: revision walk setup failed
```

alternative: `git log` and `grep`

```bash
depth=$(git log --format=%H $rev2 | grep -m1 -n -x $rev1 | cut -d: -f1)
```

`grep -m1` will stop `git log` after the first match, so there is no error