# How to clone only a specified range of commits, omitting both newer and older ones to save bandwidth

Tags: git

#### Task:

To do `git bisect` on a repo say `https://example.git` , with both the ends of the bisecting range being quite older: say: `za3bca` (newer) and `fabce1` (older).

Being on limited bandwidth, I don't want to download all the commits up to the latest end of the range as I know for sure I don't need them.

#### My approach:

So, as given on this [git documentation page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) for `git clone`, I want to use both the options: `--depth <depth>` and `--shallow-since=<date>` together.

- I will specify the date of the older end of the range, e.g. `20220212` (yyyymmdd),
- I've [counted the number of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31998123/8395964) in between the range (to say `100`), and will supply some more than that as the "depth"

```
git clone https://example.git --shallow-since=20220212 --depth 100
```

But doing this gives the error: `fatal: error processing shallow info: 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: first, your `--shallow-since` datespec doesn't parse correctly. Try `2022-02-12` instead.

But that still won't do what you want, because `--depth` and `--shallow-since` both specify how far *back* to go from the ref that's being checked out (the remote's primary branch `HEAD`, if not specified). You can't use `--depth` to specify how far *forward* to go from the commit that `--shallow-since` finds.

If there's a tag or a branch head at or near the end of your bisect range, you could use that as the ref to check out with the `--branch` option (despite the name, it accepts both branches and tags):

```
git clone --single-branch --shallow-since=2022-02-12 --branch=end-point https://some.repo
```

If there isn't, then I don't think there's much you can do, other than convince someone to make such a tag or branch for you :)

Comment: On the last line, rather than convincing someone else, the online computers (like github codespaces) can be used as well if available. In fact before this answer, I was thinking of making a new branch in the CLI on codespaces, and then cloning that custom branch locally. Also, having some way to know the size of commit range would help a lot as well.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way is tag the tips you're starting from on the server side and fetch those with `--shallow-since`. Many servers these days are configured to let you fetch arbitrary reachable (and some, even unreachable) commits, specifically to cater to this kind of bit-scrimping impulse, so if it's annoying to tag them you can try looking them up and specifying the start commit explicitly:

```
git fetch origin --shallow-since=2022212 \
        +602c0cb92c50a259c29138d8e107615569c0767d:refs/tags/starthere
```