# Get range of commits in git

Tags: git, logging, range

I need to get git commits from within a specific range, so I've been using

```
git log old_commit..new_commit
```

It works great apart when there was only 1 new commit added, and that old and new commit were either `git commit -m ''` or `git pull`

For example:

```
commit XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Merge: XXXXXXY XXXXXXZ
Author: name <name@domain.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 20 11:45:33 2015 +0200

    Merge branch 'master' of xxxxxx.xx:xxxxxxx

commit XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXY
Author: name <name@domain.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 20 11:45:05 2015 +0200

    some commit message here
```

(Mind you the sequence could be in a different order - merge first then commit)

My point is, when I do:

```
git log XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXY..XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

it behaves unexpectedly and instead of 1 (last) commit, it outputs a lot more others.

Am I doing something wrong? Are merges and commits considered as one or something?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`old..new` actually means, literally, *All commits reachable by new that are not reachable by old*. You can replace `reachable` here by `is an ancestor of`.

Since your `new` is a merge commit, the output of `old..new` will be all the commits that are not ancestors of `old`.

[image]

In the above illustration, commits point to their parents (i.e. the direction of arrows is `child --> parent`)

Comment: So in order to ignore E, F and G in the example, i.e. contents of a branch that was merged, you can add option `--first-parent`. This filters out commits that belong to other branches in case of non-fast-forward merges and only shows the merge commit.