# How to get git parent branch name from current branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Currently I am in a feature branch, but I don't know whether it was created from my develop or release branch.

Can anyone please tell me how I can get the parent branch name from the current git branch.

Comment: not sure the questions are same but you can get answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-git-branch

Comment: @Md.KhairulHasan The question is actually the same as you linked directly to this question again :)

Comment: You can only have decorated graphs, with that you can find, otherwise there is no direct command to find parent branch in git

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given that Git uses a directed acyclic graph and usually a repo only has one root, all your branches point back to one initial commit. So what you actually want is the branch that shares *the largest part* of its history with your branch.

You cannot just look for a branch whose HEAD is contained in your current branch’s history, as this branches HEAD will most likely have moved since then.

So I recommend you use `git merge-base`, which finds the newest common ancestor (aka fork point) of two branches or commits:

```
$ git merge-base feature develop
12345abc
$ git merge-base feature release
98765fed
```

This will output the two commits that appear in the history of both branches, respectively. One of the two will be contained in *both* branches, so you can feed them to `merge-base` again to get the commit you want (or rather, the one you *don’t* want):

```
git merge-base 12345abc 98765fed
98765fed
```

So in our example, `feature` was derived from `develop`, as the two share a commit that `release` does not have.

Note that this will only work if you don’t do criss-cross-merges between feature and develop.

Comment: FWIW, comparing against what the tool gitup shows is parent, this method is produces a correct result.

Answer (score 14):

So far this worked for me. You can use this as terminal alias in Mac or any type of shortcut on Windows.

```
git log --pretty=format:'%D' HEAD^ | grep 'origin/' | head -n1 | sed 's@origin/@@' | sed 's@,.*@@'
```

As explained in many places, it is not a direct parent, it gives you nearest branch which from current branch is created created or shares same HEAD^

Comment: FWIW, comparing against what the tool gitup shows is parent, this is incorrect.

Comment: This seems to be the only one that works so far. Other options that I have explored give me inconsistent results and lots of warnings. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

This one (from https://hankchizljaw.com/notes/24/) works for me:

```
git show-branch -a | grep '\*' | grep -v `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//'
```

Comment: FWIW, comparing against what the tool gitup shows is parent, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

```
#!/bin/bash
git show-branch -a 2>/dev/null \
| grep '\*' \
| grep -v `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` \
| head -n1 \
| perl -ple 's/\[[A-Za-z]+-\d+\][^\]]+$//; s/^.*\[([^~^\]]+).*$/$1/'
```

source: https://gist.github.com/joechrysler/6073741?permalink_comment_id=2391826#gistcomment-2391826

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer by following [this](https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/how-to-check-the-parent-branch-in-git-with-code-examples/) link.

```
git show-branch -a | grep '\*' | grep -v `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//'
```

Go to your project and open git bash(right click and select Git Bash Here) and past above command.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to phrase the question is:

`What is the nearest commit that resides on a branch other than the current branch, and which branch is that?`

This can be done with the command line command:

```
git show-branch \
| sed "s/].*//" \
| grep "\*" \
| grep -v "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" \
| head -n1 \
| sed "s/^.*\[//"
```

Answer taken from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17843908/8079979

Answer (score 0):

I work in a Git repo with thousands of branches, and when I wonder:

> From which branch did I start my feature branch?

I know the answer will be one of a small set of branches. Also, the approach I use to determine the answer is (IMHO) conceptually a little easier to determine, using the [2-dot syntax of log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69559520/184546).

Here's the bash alias that I use:

```
alias find-git-start-branch='for branch in \
  origin/next origin/develop origin/release origin/master origin/hotfix \
  ; do echo "Num commits not reachable by $branch: \
  $(git log $branch.. --oneline | wc -l)"; done'
```

(If you don't want the alias you can simply run the text between the single quotes.)

Line 2 is where I list the branches I wish to consider as the starting branch.

The meat of the script is all in the last line, and note that: `git log origin/develop..` is just shorthand for `git log origin/develop..HEAD`.

That [2-dot syntax](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_double_dot) lists all commits on HEAD that aren't reachable by `origin/develop`, and that is **exactly** what you typically wish to know when determining from which branch you started from. Here's an example output when I run my alias against a branch I picked up after a day or two:

```
$ find-git-start-branch
Num commits not reachable by origin/next:   3
Num commits not reachable by origin/develop:   76
Num commits not reachable by origin/release:   86
Num commits not reachable by origin/master:   290
Num commits not reachable by origin/hotfix:   290
```

The smallest number represents the branch you started from, and should be the number of *new* commits on your branch, since then.