# git: Why is it so difficult to get the parent branch name?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-strategy

It is difficult to find the parent-branch in git ...

My current solution:

```
git show-branch -a 2>/dev/null \
| grep '\*' \
| grep -v `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` \
| head -n1 \
| perl -ple 's/\[[A-Za-z]+-\d+\][^\]]+$//; s/^.*\[([^~^\]]+).*$/$1/'
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74314172/633961

**Why** is it difficult to find the parent-branch in git?

This question is not about "how to solve this?". It is about "why is it not straight forward?"

Comment: what is a "parent" branch? Is it the branch where a branch is created from? Probably because nothing about that is saved about a branch. A branch is **just** a pointer to a commit.

Comment: I think `parent branch` is a false concept. Any ref including branches is a non-persistent reference, as we can rename, delete and recreate it. So, which is the parent and which is the child, is not a fixed relationship.

Comment: Because Git is based on the DAG (directed acyclic graph) concept.

Comment: Because there is no such thing as a parent branch in git. You're asking your car to cook food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git doesn't store anything about *branches*.

A commit is an object which points to its parent, and you will have a relationship between *commits*, but a branch is just a name that points to a commit -- a shallow reference with no extra data.

In standard git, there is no information stored which keep track of : "branch x was initially created from y, then was merged with branch z on june 16th, then was reset on that day, then ...".

You can only do guess work based on the current commit graph, and the current state of other branches.

This guess work leads to commands such as the one you quoted.

You should also note that depending on the way you manage branches in your own repository, some of these commands may work for someone else but not for you.

Comment: what do you think about `git show-branch --merge-base` ?

Answer (score 2):

It's worth reading; https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References.

Then take a look at the content of `.git/refs/heads/master` or any equivalent file in that folder. It's just a file containing a commit hash. That's what a branch is.

The point is that the *original* commit hash or ref is not stored for a branch. Only the *current* commit hash is stored for the branch.

Comment: As an aside, if the ref was always local then you can use the reflog; https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog. This doesn't work for refs that you fetched from remotes.