# How can I find out how many commits in master are not in my branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, rebase

We are using GitHub to store our code repositories, and we would like all developers to ensure that branches are up to date with master before doing local developer testing, and merging.

There are two ways of updating a branch with the commits of master:

1. Merge `master` into my branch `feature_branch`, and push `feature_branch`
2. Rebase my branch `feature_branch` onto master, and force push `feature_branch`.

Given that the team in question is currently using 1. (merge workflow), how can I see:

1. The **number of commits** that are in the remote `master` branch, but not in the remote `feature_branch`.
2. A true value if the number in 1 is >0, otherwise false.

It would be most preferable to have something that integrates with GitHub do this, but I'd like to know how to do this from the command line as well.

I know that I can do a `git diff master..feature_branch`, but that actually gives me all the changes (and is for the local branches). I just want to know the number of commits ahead and behind, in the same manner than it is shown between local `master` and remote `master`

Comment: "force push" is asking for trouble down the road.

Comment: yes, it can be, but there are pros and cons, one pro being a cleaner history, but this question is not intended to discuss rebase vs merge workflow. Force pushing a feature branch that one guy is working on is not really a problem in my eyes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Jeff Puckett II's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38526806/1256452) is fine, and you should follow his [link to this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/4233593) as well.  But what you want is in fact built directly in to Git:

```
git rev-list --count master..feature
```

and:

```
git rev-list --count feature..master
```

which you might want to combine into very short alias or script:

```
echo feature is $(git rev-list --count master..feature) commits ahead of master
echo and $(git rev-list --count feature..master) commits behind master
```

This is, in fact, just what `git status` and `git branch -vv` do, although they check for zero-commits-ahead-or-behind first too.

Here's a short (very short, for me :-) ) explanation.

#### Git's `log` and `rev-list` are almost the same command

Both `git log` and `git rev-list` look at a whole range of commits.  The most important difference is that `git log` shows you the *log messages* (and optionally, patches), while `git rev-list` shows you just the raw commit hashes, by default.

You can, however, get `git rev-list` to give you a *count* of *how many* commits it would have listed, instead of their raw hash IDs.  And, as you will see in pretty diagrams on [that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/4233593), the `stop..start` two-dot syntax (***except in `git diff`*** which is very special<sup>1</sup>) tells Git "give me all the commits you can find starting from `start`, *excluding* all the commits you can find starting from `stop`".

If you find all the commits that are on `feature`, then take away all the commits that are on *both* branches, you're left with only the commits that are *only* on `feature`.  Then you have `git rev-list` *count* them.  These are the commits you're "ahead", so that's how far ahead you are.

(Having `git log` log them, each on one line, then getting `wc` to count the lines, also works, of course.)

Reversing the two names, with `feature..master`, has Git find commits that are on `master`, then take away commits on both branches.  These are the ones you're "behind".

The output of `git rev-list` is rarely useful for humans, and is mainly intended to be used in scripts.  In fact, that's just what I suggested above: a two line script (or even just one line, but that did not fit very well on my screen here).

Here's a question for thought: how do we know to use the names `master` and `feature`?  How could we instruct *Git* to know this?  But let's leave that for later.

---

<sup>1</sup>The issue here is that `git diff` *desperately wants* to work with at most *two* commits.  The range notations with two and three dots, `master..feature` or `master...feature`, usually produce a long list of commits.  Git's `diff` can't handle these anyway.  It *could* just refuse to take these notations—which would have been quite reasonable, really—but instead, the Git authors decided they'd re-use the notations to mean something related.

This means that whatever you've learned about using `master..feature` with `git diff`, you must forget it all whenever dealing with other Git commands.  *Sic transit gloria Git.*

Comment: There is a small typo here `echo and $(git rev-list --count master..feature) commits behind master`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `diff`

```
git diff master..feature
```

use `log`

```
git log master..feature
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/4233593) for a great explanation.

So if you just want the count, then use `--oneline` and pipe it to word count line.

```
git log --oneline master..feature | wc -l
```

Comment: But that gives me a whole bunch of detail about them. 
I just want to see `1 commit ahead, 2 commits behind master`

Comment: git branch -v can show info like `1 commit ahead` or git branch -vv

Comment: @John that's the output, so use oneline and pipe to line count