# Git diff between two tags with username

Tags: git, github, git-diff

I can do following:

```
git diff tag1 tag2 --stat
```

But this gives me list of files.. How can I know all users who have worked between these two tags !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A first approach could use [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

In the git repo itself:

```
 git log v2.9.0..v2.9.3 --name-only --format="%aN <%aE>" --reverse
 git log <olderTag>..<newerTag> --name-only --format="%aN <%aE>" --reverse
                   ^^
                    |_ don't forget the two dots.
```

(On the git dots syntax, see "[What are the differences between double-dot “..” and triple-dot “…” in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/6309)")

That gives:

```
Eric Wong <e@80x24.org>

daemon.c
Edward Thomson <xx@xx>

pretty.c
t/t6006-rev-list-format.sh
David Kastrup <xx@gxx>

builtin/blame.c
René Scharfe <xx@xx>

t/t4051-diff-function-context.sh
t/t4051/appended1.c
t/t4051/appended2.c
t/t4051/dummy.c
t/t4051/hello.c
t/t4051/includes.c
```

....

And to get just the list of unique contributors:

```
git log v2.9.0..v2.9.3 --format="%aN <%aE>" --reverse|sort|uniq
```

That returns:

```
Alex Henrie <xx@xx.com>
Alfred Perlstein <xx@xx.org>
Andreas Brauchli <a.xx@xx.net>
Andrew Oakley <xx@xx.com>
Armin Kunaschik <xx@xx.com>
Charles Bailey <xx@xx.net>
Charles Bailey <xx@xx.org>
Chris Packham <xx@xx.com>
Dave Nicolson <xx@xx.com>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it VonC. I did not get results; I was doing git diff between two tags; I want ONLY those users who have modified the code between these two tags.. How will git log solve the problem and not use git diff

Comment: @Deepak it will solve the problem in that it lists all the commits authors between two tags, meaning the users who have modified the code between these two tags.

Comment: In your example are v2.9.0. .v2.9.3   and two tags ??

Comment: Yes, replace them by your own tags.

Comment: I was trying same. git log release-20160823-262 release-20160831-266 --format="%aN <%aE>" --reverse|sort|uniq   is giving me list of ALL users ; even some users who have left us long ago

Comment: @Deepak did you put '..' between the two tags? `git log release-20160823-262..release-20160831-266 --format="%aN <%aE>" --reverse|sort|uniq`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122505/discussion-between-deepak-and-vonc).