# How do I list files modified on another branch?

Tags: git

Before I merge branch B into branch A, I'd like to see a list of files modified (or added, deleted, etc.) on branch B. I know I can:

```
git diff --name-only B
```

But that list includes files changed on A as well. I only want to see files that were changed on B (but it's okay if they were also changed on A).

This is pretty close:

```
git log --name-only ..B
```

But that splits the list into separate commits. How can I generate a single list of files modified on B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider "[What are the differences between double-dot “..” and triple-dot “…” in Git diff commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6309)", you can try:

```
git diff --name-only A...B
```

(you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/6309) the git commit ranges used by `git log`)

Comment: This is no doubt the right answer (and upvoted) but it's worth mentioning that any time you ask "what changed", you're implicitly assuming a *starting point*. ("What changed at the grocery store?" "Well, 50 years ago, there was no store, then they broke ground..." "No, I mean, *since yesterday*." "Oh.") In order to show you *what changed*, you have to specify a *since when*. The point of the `A...B` notation is to have Git find a suitable "since when" for you.