# How to download a github "Compare Changes" result as a patch?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

Github has a compare feature that can be used to compare changes across different forks. e.g. [How can I diff two branches in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552274/how-can-i-diff-two-branches-in-github)

Question: how can I download the result of such a compare as a patch file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `.patch` to the end of the URL. An example Compare page:

[https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/9693336...1bbcfa5](https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/969333610c6ecf653922b84ea51128a16ed18ad2...1bbcfa5683c203eb92a0d9571f63043791bea695)

and its formatted patch:

[https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/9693336...1bbcfa5**.patch**](https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/969333610c6ecf653922b84ea51128a16ed18ad2...1bbcfa5683c203eb92a0d9571f63043791bea695.patch)