# How to visually see diff between two git commits on github

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I understand I can run a git command locally to see them in the terminal, but I want to see them visually on github. Is this possibly?

I want to be able to see the diff between two commits, NOT two branches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I diff two branches in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552274/how-can-i-diff-two-branches-in-github)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+diff+two+commits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - you can compare two commits via the `compare` UI:

```
https://github.com/orgname/reponame/compare/<hash1>...<hash2>
```

You can find the hash values by visiting the `Commits` tab and copying the commit hash for each commit you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

To compare the two commits `c3a414e` and `faf7c6f` from the `linguist` repository go to https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/c3a414e..faf7c6f.

See [Comparing Commits](https://help.github.com/en/articles/comparing-commits-across-time#comparing-commits) in the GitHub documentation.