# diff branch changes in git relative to common ancestor

Tags: git, command-line-interface, diff

I find myself recurrently in a situation, where I want to see the diff of all changes, that a branch introduced since branching off. The naive

```
$ git diff ..branch
```

doesn't work well, because changes in `master` are taken into account as well. What I'm looking for is basically a nicer way to run

```
$ git diff $(git merge-base master branch)..branch
```

or expressed in graphics:

```
---A---B---C---D---E  <== master
        \
         F---G---H    <== branch
```

How do I elegantly find the diff between `B` and `H`?

**Edit:** As noted in my answer below, `master...branch` is a solution to my problem. However, I still don't know, why that's the case, given the quoted man page snippet.

Why does `diff master...branch` only show the differences from the merge base, while `man rev-parse` says, it should include `master`'s commits, too?

Why does `diff master..branch` show the diff between the current state of `master` and `branch`, while `man rev-parse` says, it should ignore the `master`-only commits?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In a comment on it, @ELLIOTTCABLE points to the full story at [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com/463027#463027). As a comment there notes: *It's pretty ridiculous how the meaning of .. and ... is exactly swapped for log and diff: log A..B is changes from merge base to B which is what diff A...B does*.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After extensively looking at `git help rev-parse` and experimenting around, I found this piece of information:

```
   <rev1>..<rev2>
       Include commits that are reachable from <rev2> but exclude those
       that are reachable from <rev1>. When either <rev1> or <rev2> is
       omitted, it defaults to HEAD.

   <rev1>...<rev2>
       Include commits that are reachable from either <rev1> or <rev2>
       but exclude those that are reachable from both. When either <rev1>
       or <rev2> is omitted, it defaults to HEAD.
```

Somehow I was always under the impression, that `master..branch` is what I need and forgot about `master...branch` (with three dots).

But experimenting with it showed, that the three-dot notation is exactly what I'm looking for:

```
$ git diff master...branch
```

shows only the differences of `branch` relative to where it took off of `master`.

Comment: _Nota bene_: I have no idea why, though. Even after reading the man page for the umpteenth time, I still think, that `master..branch` should've do what I want.

Comment: This is definitely the answer; and as this is the first Google result (at least in my search-bubble!), you might want to mark your own answer as ‘accepted.’ Oh, and as for the explanation as to *why* this is the case — basically backwards compatibility. The `rev-parse` documentation actually doesn't apply here; it's documented directly in `git help diff` instead. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/463027/31897)

Comment: Thank you, @ELLIOTTCABLE! Good to know, where that difference comes from.

Comment: Incorrect (I think). This works for commands like log, but diff is different. See git help diff:

```
    git diff [<options>] <commit>..<commit> [--] [<path>...]
      This is synonymous to the earlier form (without the "..") for viewing the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.

    git diff [<options>] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>...]
      This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second <commit>, starting at a common ancestor of both <commit>. "git diff A...B" is equivalent to "git diff $(git merge-base A B) B".
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but isn’t that basically what ELLIOTTCABLE said two comments above? (Or put another way, I do not see, how my answer to _my own_ question might be incorrect with regard to “does this address the problem?”, inaccuracies in the explanation notwithstanding.)

Answer (score 3):

> What I'm looking for is basically a nicer way to run
>
> ```
> $ git diff $(git merge-base master branch)..branch
> ```

How about creating an alias?

```
git config alias.diffbr '!f() { git diff $(git merge-base master $1)..$1; }; f'
```

Then you can simply do `git diffbr branch`.

If you want the alias to be available for all repositories on your machine add the [`--global` argument to `git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config---global).

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed your answer. Yes, an alias is what I currently consider doing. Do you by chance know about a revision notation, that would allow addressing things easier? (Sometimes I do weird stuff with `diff`, where an alias might get in the way.)

Comment: @Boldewyn, I'm not clear on what you need in a revision notation. But it looks like you've found another, much simpler solution of your own. I'll assume you're all set unless I hear otherwise.

Comment: Yes, indeed (although I'm still puzzled by that man page). Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to check the current branch against where you branch off, just add `...`.  So the command would look like

```
git diff master...
```

It's the same as `git diff master...HEAD`. I am running git version 2.17.1. This might behave differently in an older version.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not the answer you're looking for here, but it might help someone else. Using a graphical tool like gitk, you can:

- Open gitk
- Click on H, right click and select "Mark this commit"
- Click on B, right click and select "Diff this -> marked commit"

Now you see all updated files to the right, and all the modified lines (per file) to the left.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But yes, I'm looking for a CLI way. (Upvoted regardless.)