# Why double-dot vs triple-dot in git behaves different for diff and log

Tags: git

First of all: There are already two questions on StackOverflow with solid answers regarding this topic, but I'm still puzzling. I sort of understand the 'what', but not the 'why'.

- [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com)
- [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git diff commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-dif)

My question is: Why shows `git log A..B` **(double dot)** the list of commits from B to A, but in order to get the diff of the same set of commits one has to write `git diff A...B` **(triple dot)**.

Wouldn't it be much more consistent if `git log` and `git diff` would treat commit ranges the same way? They now appear to behave orthogonal to each other.

Maybe I'm missing some kind of insight about why it is designed like this?

[image: Git log vs diff]

Comment: Mort's answer is pretty good, but ultimately, when you ask "why did person *X* do action *Y*" we all wind up having to speculate, unless person X wrote down his/her reasons. You'd have to ask Linus, perhaps. Note that when using `A..B` in `git log`, you never see commit `A` itself, while when using `git diff A..B`, one of the two inputs is `A` itself: another inconsistency of sorts.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to speculate. Often there will be public discourse *somewhere* about it and that can be referenced to answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

It seems it was simply a [mistake in design](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAEW0o+gYqWT5u-Tf8aDoMgXaf36Mb-XOApLNs4D+GMVLvsOjxg@mail.gmail.com/T/):

*Junio C Hamano @ 2019-12-23 18:02*:

> Please unlearn dot-dot and three-dots when using "git diff", which
> is not about ranges but about comparing two endpoints.  If we were
> reinventing Git today from scratch, we would make "git diff A..B" an
> error.  You can consider it a bug that the command accepts a range
> notation, but this will not change any time soon without a large
> fight to find and fix uses of the syntax in scripts by longtime Git
> users have written over the years.

> Allowing dot-dot on the command line of "git diff", instead of
> diagnosing them as errors and dying, was a stupid mistake we (well,
> mostly Linus, but I am willing to take the blame too) made due to
> laziness when we reused the machinery, which we invented to parse
> the command line of "log" family of commands to specify ranges, to
> parse the command line of "diff", which accidentally ended up
> allowing the syntax for ranges where it shouldn't be allowed.

> And worse yet, since there was only dot-dot and three-dots came much
> later, "git diff A..B" ended up comparing the endpoints A and B,
> because there didn't even A...B notation exist.

> This is not limited to you but any user of modern Git is better off
> to pretend "git diff A..B" does not exist; please unlearn dot-dot
> and three-dots when using "git diff" and you'd be happier.

If you're wondering who Junio is:

> Junio Hamano (Japanese: 濱野 純) is a software engineer and hacker from Japan. He is best known for leading a large team of software developers who maintain Git. Linus Torvalds, the original developer, has said that one of his big successes was recognizing Hamano's skills as a developer.

Answer (score 4):

`git diff` always operates on *just two commits* (refs), never more never fewer, and shows the differences between them. It is not doing anything with a "range", just two commits.

`git log`, on the other hand, displays ranges of commits, and you can specify any number of ranges in a number of different ways. So right there, you see that git diff and git log are going to behave differently.

I don't think you can even compare two commits with a range of commits. I think it's more that "The `..` syntax is a shorthand for 'from .. to' and that shorthand will mean different things in different contexts. But then we realized that there's a very frequently needed 'from the last common ancestor of .. to' idiom in `git diff`, so we made the similar, but slightly different `...` syntax."

Comment: In my mind: `git diff A..B` = `git diff $( git merge-base A B )..B`

Comment: @eftshift0 - that is not right. That is the definition of `git diff A...B`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff