# Why doesn't Git keep track of the changes made in README.md files?

Tags: git, github

I have this repository and update the source code within README file almost every day. After pushing the changes to the repository in the terminal, I update the README.md file via the browser every time. And `git status` says everything is up to date with my remote repository after these actions.

But the problem is when I push something git says *Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally.* and I have to pull the changes made in README.md. So, why doesn't Git keep track of the changes made in README.md files and says everything is up to date?

Comment: `git status` only display change locally: you need to _fetch_ or _pull_ remote changes for them to appear.

Comment: Is there a way of view the changes between local and remote repositories?

Comment: Once you do a `git fetch`, then `git status` will say something like "Your branch and origin/main have diverged," and will tell you how many commits are on each side of the divergence. You can use `git diff` double and triple dot notations to see the differences you are interested in (see the visual [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120060/why-double-dot-vs-triple-dot-in-git-behaves-different-for-diff-and-log)).