# how to find list of all commits between local branches and remote branches?

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull, git-log, git-fetch

I am trying to find out list of commits between remote repository and local repository across all branches. How do generate this commit list?

I have tried on my local machine running git log command with various options. It does not give me right results.

I expect output of all commits.
4722ec2ac7b8a69ff1ed901a922cf3cd268033f8

Comment: Can you give a better example of the output you're aiming to get? A unique commits list for all branches at once sounds odd. Do you in fact expect a list of lists?

Comment: Could you offer more details on what is it exactly that you want, so I may rectify my answer?

Comment: Tell us what you think about my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit:

After fooling in the comments a bit, we arrived at this oneliner:

```sh
git branch --format='%(refname:short)' | xargs -I{} git log --pretty=format:"%H" origin/{}...{}
```

It iterates over your local branch names (assuming there exists a remote version with the same name for each of them) and prints the hashes of the commits that are present in either one of the remote or local branches, but not in both.

---

### Original answer:

First run a `git fetch` to update your remote tracking branches, then try this:

```sh
git log --pretty=format:"%H" --all origin/master...master
```

This will show what commits are not in origin/master and master at the same time.

That triple-dot syntax is all over git commands (there's also the double-dot one); they're not exactly consistent though and I recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/11615853) if you want to dig deeper.

The `--all` shows the other branches as well.

You can tune it more to your liking by messing around with the dots, order, the `--all` flag, and even the `^` operator.

### Bonus:

You could devise a strategy to still use the iterative solution without a strict one to one mapping of local branches to remote branches with a simple text file and then just cat piping it into xargs.

Comment: `--all` is ignored when a commit or range is explicitly given. Also consider a `--pretty=format:"%H"` instead of `--oneline --graph` since OP wanted a simple list of commit hashes. But the problematic point remains the need to run this for each branch with its remote counterpart.

Comment: That is not correct. `--all` will actually bring all commits and if they are not in either of the branches listed, they will show up.
Your suggested formatting will only make it worse for whoever is reading it.
Ultimately, I did say it is not *exactly* what he asked.

Comment: I don't get your point about hte format I suggested : didn't OP ask for a list of hashes? If the list is to be fed to a script, which is unknown to us at this point, `--oneline --graph` output is useless. My remark tried to stick to OP's question.

Comment: You're right. I was answering several questions and got it mixed up. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I was thinking: if he just wants a list of hashes of commits regardless of context, we could iterate over all branches and compare `origin/${branch}...${branch}`.
Something like `git branch --format='%(refname:short)' | xargs -I{} git log --pretty=format:"%H" origin/{}...{}`. What do you guys think?

Comment: I was on the same train of thoughts you are. But ironically enough (not that it's rare but...) it seems we two care more than OP after all XD. Upvoted for tenacity! (but editing the answer is better than just commenting, as a sidenote)