# How to count commits behind/ahead between upstream and local branch?

Tags: git, github

When you have upstream that is different from origin, how you can count difference between local and upstream?

`git rev-list --count upstream/master..master` returns 0 despite the fact that upstream is few commits ahead of local master branch.

Comment: `git rev-list` works for me. Could you show the output of `git branch -a -v`? (or even better, an screenshot of `gitk --all`?

Comment: @MondKin `gitk --all` output:
* master <commit behind upstream commit>
remotes/origin/HEAD <commit behind upstream commit>
remotes/origin/master <commit behind upstream commit>
remotes/upstream/master <commit behind upstream commit>

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the three-dot notation and the `--left-right` flag:

```
git rev-list --left-right --count upstream/master...master
```

As described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), the three-dot notation `A...B` produces a [*symmetric difference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of the sets of commits *reachable from* the two identifiers or hash IDs `A` and `B`.  (For much more on *reachability*, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).)

Normally this would just be:

- all commits on `upstream/master` that aren't on `master`, plus
- all commits on `master` that aren't on `upstream/master`

which would just be a sum.  But adding `--left-right` tells Git to *split* the sets into two.  Without `--count`, you get a listing annotated with `<` and `>` markers to tell you which commit hash goes with which identifier.  With `--count`, you get two counts.  In this case, if `upstream/master` is strictly ahead of `master`, the first count will be nonzero and the second count will be zero.  For instance, if `upstream/master` is 2 ahead, the output is `2 0`.

This works if you reverse the names, too; it's just that now the counts are swapped around.  For the above case, you'd now get `0 2`.

Pick whichever order you like and get both counts, or use the two-dot notation to get just one count.  The one count you get, with `A..B`, is the count of commits reachable from `B` but not reachable from `A`.  If `upstream/master` is "ahead" and you want that count, you need `master..upstream/master` when using the two-dot method.

Answer (score 1):

The number of commits upstream is ahead of master:

```
git rev-list --count master..upstream/master
```

`master..upstream/master` is the range of commits that are in upstream but not in master. It's equivalent to `upstream/master ^master`.

See [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com) for more information.