# What is the difference between "git show ..origin/master:somefile" and "git show origin/master:somefile"

Tags: git

For context, from my own feature branch I am using the following commands:

```
> git fetch
> git show ..origin/master:somefile > ../external_folder/somefile
```

to ensure that I have the latest copy of a file from origin/master to read from without overwriting my own branch's.

<strike>The above works but if I omit the two dots from the git show command, the file I get is the same as my branch's even though a newer one has been pushed to origin/master.</strike>

Can someone explain what the difference is? Also, if it makes any difference the file in question is a blob.

edit: I was mistaken:

```
> git show ..origin/master:somefile > ../external_folder/somefile
```

produces an empty file and I misinterpreted the diff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use `git show origin/master:somefile` here, without the two leading dots.  The `git show` command probably *should* complain about `..origin/master:somefile`: print an error message to stderr, and no output at all to stdout.

With the versions of Git I have handy, `git show ..<rev>:path` produces no output at all (and exits successfully!), even though the given path exists in both commits.  So if I were to use your:

```
git show ..origin/master:somefile > ../external_folder/somefile
```

I would always end up with an *empty* `../external_folder/somefile` file.  I conclude that your Git version must predate Git 1.7.11.3.

#### Long-ish

The `<rev1>..<rev2>` syntax mostly<sup>1</sup> means *select a range of commits*, with the range being determined by invoking `git rev-list`, more or less as if you had run:

```
git log ^$(git rev-parse rev1) $(git rev-parse rev2)
```

You can see this effect more directly if you just run `git rev-parse` yourself:

```
$ git rev-parse master~2..master
b994622632154fc3b17fb40a38819ad954a5fb88
^41eae3eaa81c5f2b61b2610ed74de15c4291b318
```

The name `master`, in this particular Git repository, selects commit `b994622632154fc3b17fb40a38819ad954a5fb88`.  The relative expression `master~2` selects commit `41eae3eaa81c5f2b61b2610ed74de15c4291b318`.

Omitting one of the two names means *pretend I wrote `HEAD`* so since `HEAD` is currently `master`, we also get:

```
git rev-parse master~2..
b994622632154fc3b17fb40a38819ad954a5fb88
^41eae3eaa81c5f2b61b2610ed74de15c4291b318
```

Commands like `git log` or `git cherry-pick` can take a range of commits like this.  The set of commits selected by this range expression is:

- all commits reachable from the non-negated (no `^` prefix) commit, excluding
- all commits reachable from the negated (`^`-prefixed) commit.

So if we have:

```
...--E--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

then `master~2..master`, or—shorter but identical in meaning—`HEAD~2..` selects commits `G` and `H`, because `master` (or `HEAD`) means *commit `H`* while `master~2` (or `HEAD~2`) means *commit `F`*.  We select all commits up through and including commit `H`, but then knock out all commits up through and including commit `F`, leaving just `G` and `H` here.

The `git show` command, however, normally shows just one thing: one commit or one file, for instance.  So the notion of giving it a *range* expression makes no sense (but see below).  The command can, however, show individual files, and it does that when the revision expression you supply names a blob object:

```
$ git rev-parse master:Makefile
3d3a39fc192d5544a411d4cedb3785473b6f1148
$ git cat-file -t 3d3a39fc192d5544a411d4cedb3785473b6f1148
blob
```

So when `git show master:Makefile` is given a revision expression that resolves to a single blob object like this, `git show` shows the contents of that blob object.

Now consider:

```
$ git rev-parse master~2..master:Makefile
3d3a39fc192d5544a411d4cedb3785473b6f1148
^41eae3eaa81c5f2b61b2610ed74de15c4291b318
```

While hash IDs are big, ugly, and hard to remember or get right, we can actually *see* here that what we're giving `git show` is:

- the non-negated hash ID of the blob object we'd like to see, *plus*
- the negated hash ID of the *commit* `master~2`.

As it turns out, [commit `c5941f1aac071addc1c9b0781c323b588c542420`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5941f1aac071addc1c9b0781c323b588c542420), which first went public in Git 1.7.11.3, modified the `git show` command to act very much like `git log` when given a commit range:

```
git show master~2..master
```

works much like running:

```
git rev-list master~2..master | while read commit; do git show $commit; done
```

There are a few differences.  In particular, `git log` by default *does not* show a patch for merge commits, but `git show` by default shows a patch as if you had used `git log --cc`.  (The other difference is less important here: the shell variant, with the `while read commit; do ...; done` sequence, has to spawn multiple `git show` commands.)

Note that invoking `git rev-list` this way produces no output:

```
$ git rev-list master~2..master:Makefile
$
```

That's because the second (non-negated) hash ID is that of a blob object, and blob objects do not participate in revision walking.  So this amounts to *select no commits, while excluding all commits reachable from `master~2`*.

The fact that all of this runs and exits quietly, without complaint, is almost certainly a bug.  Mixing commit hashes and tag-or-blob hashes in a `..` or `...` expression should just draw an error from the revision parsing code, I think.

---

<sup>1</sup>The reason for the adverb *mostly* here is that a few commands have special handling.  In particular, both `git diff` and `git rebase` play special tricks with the two- and/or three-dot syntax: they don't just let `git rev-list` do the work.

Comment: Thank you, this clears things up a lot. On taking a second look `git show origin/master:somefile > ../external_folder/somefile` without the dots does work like I needed it to. I must have made a mistake somewhere

Answer (score 0):

from the git-documentation:

> ... in these two shorthand notations, you can omit one end and let it default to HEAD. For example, `origin..` is a shorthand for *origin..HEAD* and asks "What did I do since I forked from the origin branch?" Similarly, **`..origin` is a shorthand for *HEAD..origin* and asks "What did the origin do since I forked from them?"** Note that `..` would mean *HEAD..HEAD* which is an empty range that is both reachable and unreachable from HEAD.

Whole documentation about *dotted range notation* you can read [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)

*Git* substitutes HEAD if one side is missing -> `git show ..origin/master` becomes `git show HEAD..origin/master` and look, what did `origin` do since it forked from.

If you write without *double dot*, you take the *current* `origin` and show the content from this `origin`.

[image]

In the example from the picture above, with `..experiment` you will see the stood from the red point. If you write `experiment` you will see the stood from the blue point.

Picture from [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)

Have also a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com)

Comment: Thank you, I was confused about giving a range to `git show` with a specific filename because it exited without error, it seems like giving it a range doesn't make any sense in this context.