# How to list all changed files between two tags in GitPython

Tags: git, gitpython

I could use `Git` command `git log --oneline tag1 tag2` to list all commits between two tags. Then use `git show --pretty="" --name-only commitId` to list the changed files in one commit.
How to achieve this using `GitPython`?

Comment: Given that a tag tags one commit, and each commit is a snapshot, what's wrong with `git diff --name-status <tag1> <tag2>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know a git command, you can [use git directly](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly) in GitPython. Taking `git show --pretty="" --name-only HEAD` for example:

```
from git import Repo

# Suppose the current path is the root of the repository
r = Repo('.')
o = r.git.show('HEAD', pretty="", name_only=True)
print(o)
```

- Arguments like `HEAD` remain unchanged as non-keyword arguments.
- Arguments like `--pretty=""` are converted to keyword arguments by removing the leading `--`.
- Flags like `--name-only` are converted to keyword arguments by removing the leading `--` and being assigned the value `True`.
- The `-` in the keys and commands are converted to `_`. `name-only` should be `name_only`. `git for-each-ref` should be `git.for_each_ref`.
- The non-keyword arguments come before the keyword arguments.

The command `git log --oneline tag1 tag2` does not list commits between the two tags. It lists commits reachable from any of the two tags.

Comment: Thanks your reply, can  `git log --oneline tag1...tag2` list commits between the two tags?

Comment: @Kerwen I'm not sure what you expect by `between`. Check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/6330106.