# Github UI does not seem to track differences between branches when files are checked out from one branch to another

Tags: git, github, branch, difference, pull-request

My scenario is this:

1. I have a development branch (`dev`), and a production branch (`prod`) in Github.
2. In my CLI, I branch off of `prod`, checkout a set of changes from `dev`, and merge the changes into `prod` (and push to Github)
3. In the Github web UI, if I then create a pull request to `prod` with `dev` as the source, it does not show the changes that I already picked out of `dev`; it seems to be following the logic that `dev` has never been merged with `prod`, therefore ignoring the changeset which I just picked out of `dev` and merged with `prod`.

Can someone explain the logic behind this? It is extremely confusing for my team, because we regularly check out changes from `dev` and merge them to `prod`, yet Github shows all those differences as not yet merged in the pull request from `dev` to `prod`. So it appears to us that the `dev` branch is massively out of sync with the `prod` branch, when in fact, the `prod` branch contains most of the `dev` changes already.

Noting that the git CLI reflects the changes as expected: I see close parity between `dev` and `prod` when comparing the two branches on the command line. It's the Github web UI that seems to be following its own logic.

Comment: First problem that I see is that you are pushing into _prod_, not another separate branch. And what do you mean exactly when you say `checkout a set of changes from dev`?

Comment: I'm confused by this: in #2 you are merging `dev` into `prod` manually and then *push* it out. At that point `prod` now has `dev` in it. In #3 you're creating a PR for `dev` into `prod`, but you already did that in #2. Why are you doing the same thing in #2 and #3, first manually and then with a PR? Note, normally you would *only* do #3, and if you did #2 it would be only to test the merge, but you would not *push* it out. In fact, most repos wouldn't even *let* you push out important branches, as they would be locked down to only allow PRs.

Comment: please post the set of command you type, step by step

Comment: @eftshift0 the process is to branch from `prod`, check out files from `dev`, and merge them in.


@TTT since we have a lot of changes frequently, we use the pull request tool to try and see what's not been checked into the `prod` branch using `dev` as the source, to get a handle on what we might have not addressed. It seems the way that we're doing this is probably not standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a pull request from `dev` (source branch) to `prod` (target branch), or in a merge request of Gitlab, or in a pending change of Gerrit (a bit different from the 2 others), the differences displayed on the UI are the result of `git diff prod...dev`. About the difference between `git diff prod..dev` (equivalent to `git diff prod dev`) and `git diff prod...dev`, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com).

`prod...dev` compares the merge base of `dev` and `prod` against `dev`. The merge base of `dev` and `prod` is the latest common commit of the 2 branches. You can get it by `git merge-base dev prod`. The merge base can be considered as the fork point where `dev` is branched off `prod` or vice versa. It shows what codes have been changed since the fork point on `dev`.

Suppose you create `dev` from `prod` at a commit and later work on it. Before you merge `dev` back to `prod`, other developers could be constantly updating `prod`. To see what you have changed since the fork point, `git diff prod dev` is not a good method. Consider an edge case in which `prod` has been updated by others to a state exactly the same with your `dev`. If it uses `git diff prod dev`, nothing is printed as they have completely the same codes. It's unfair to say that you have done nothing. However, `git diff prod...dev` displays your work.

To display the difference on the UI as you expect, you could run `git checkout dev && git pull origin -r prod && git push origin -f dev` to rebase your `dev` onto the latest `prod`. This way, the new merge base is exactly `prod`. And now `git diff prod...dev` and `git diff prod..dev` have the same result.

Comment: I think I understand now. Github's UI is showing the changes/difference between the most recent common merge bases between the two branches.

The way we are doing things: branching off of prod, checking out files from `dev`, and merging then into `prod` does not leave any trace of a merge between `dev` and `prod`. That is why the pull request UI shows such a large changeset when we try to see what differences "remain" between dev and prod. Using `git diff` has been misleading, at least in terms of how I have been interpreting the results.