# Git: Is it possible to produce an output showing which commits differ between two branches?

Tags: git

I want to be able to do something like a git diff between two branches, but show the commit ids of which commits exist on one branch but not the other. (And vice-versa.)

Adding to the complexity, I also need to be able to see who authored these commits.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: It sounds like you need the log more than the diff?

Comment: It looks like the `git log A..B` syntax is what you might be interested in. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com) if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the commit ids of which commits exist on one branch but not the other

You can use the following command

*$git log wip..wip2 --oneline --no-merges*

[image]

And for the author name you can try shortlog .. I am sure you can use grep to do these in a same line

[image]

*$ git shortlog wip..wip2 --oneline --no-merges*

Comment: No pictures of code please.

Answer (score 0):

Consider not only the two-dot syntax (as shown in [microtechie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71646493/1256452)), but also the three-dot or [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) syntax:

```
git <insert log commands and options> br1...br2
```

where the three dots between the two branch names are literally three dots.

There's one problem, of sorts, with this: it selects all commits reachable from *either* `br1` *or* `br2`, excluding all commits reachable from *both* `br1` *and* `br2`, so this means you need some way to know *which name* reaches *which commits*.  There are two ways to get this kind of information:

1. Use the `--left-right` option, which inserts `<` or `>` markers to tell you that some commit is found via the left-side name (`br1` in this case) or the right-side name (`br2`).
2. Use `--graph` or some other graph-drawing software.

Since the *graph* is usually *extremely important*, I tend to prefer `--graph` here; `--left-right` is more for scripts.  Using `--graph` with `--oneline` is particularly useful: see [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).

Note that `--oneline` drops the author, but you can use `--graph` *without* `--oneline`, or *with* `--format=` (or `--pretty=tformat:`) and specify your own format, with whatever information you want.  Again, see [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).