# Get list of all edited files since branching

Tags: git, git-branch, git-history

I'd like to get a list of edited files since branching from my master branch (not comparing to the most recent head of master branch, but master at the point of branching).

Is this possible?

This seems like it'd be a pretty common thing to want to do, but my colleagues didn't know of git command for this, and didn't find anything online (it's kinda hard to google i guess).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are on the branch now, and the master branch is called `master`, you would say

```
git diff --name-only master...
```

The three dots cause the comparison to be with the point where you branched from master, and the `diff --name-only` lists filenames only.

---

***Footnote***

Some good Stack Overflow bookmarks to keep on hand are:

- [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git diff commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-dif)
- [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com)

The dot-notation means different things in different contexts (notably, it works differently in `diff` from how it works in `log`), so it can be annoyingly tricky to remember.

Comment: Does this assume that master is merged into HEAD? If master is not in the history of HEAD then you would also see new commits from master?

Comment: @Adam I don't know what "master is merged into HEAD" means.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you want something like;

```
git log --stat --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit topic ^origin/master
```

This will log the commit title and affected files for each commit that is reachable by topic but omit any commits that are reachable from origin/master.

In simple terms, just the files affected by topic.

Answer (score -1):

1. Get branching point (common ancestor) with `git merge-base myBranch master`. This will give you the commit, let's say `650dc022f3a65bdc78d97e2b1ac9a595a924c3f2`
2. Get diff between this commit and `myBranch` with `git diff 650dc022f3a65bdc78d97e2b1ac9a595a924c3f2 myBranch`.
3. You may want no configure `diff` to show more or less information depending on your needs.

Note: if `myBranch` has intermediate merges from `master` to `myBranch`, you will get the last merge commit as common ancestor instead of original commit where `myBranch` was initially branched from the `master`.