# Why is git log merge1..merge2 empty?

Tags: git

I have a reasonably tidy Git history, with feature branches merging into the main branch. This can be seen in the results to `git log --graph --oneline`:

```
*   f8b3a40 (HEAD -> main, upstream/main) Feature baz
|\  
| * 5044a90 baz2
| * fa0c768 baz1
|/  
*   5485e88 Feature bar
|\  
| * f10992d bar5
| * 72c6f1b bar4
| * 05f902b bar3
| * 3d32bb6 bar2
| * a8274c6 bar1
|/  
*   2449d02 Feature foo
|\  
| * 437e321 foo6
| * 5e7af85 foo5
| * 5babacb foo4
| * a66ec89 foo3
```

So I can get a nice summary with `git log --first-parent --oneline`:

```
f8b3a40 (HEAD -> main, upstream/main) Feature baz
5485e88 Feature bar
2449d02 Feature foo
7e68bab Feature fizzbuzz
```

Now I want to review the changes between foo and bar. `git diff 5485e88..2449d02` works as expected, I can see all the code changes. But `git log 5485e88..2449d02` is empty. I am expecting something like:

```
commit 5485e88
Author: Jimmy Weasel <jimmy@example.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 22 15:49:53 2023 +0000

Feature bar...

commit f10992d
Author: Jimmy Weasel <jimmy@example.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 22 15:25:03 2023 +0000

bar5...

commit 72c6f1b
Author: Jimmy Weasel <jimmy@example.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 22 15:22:01 2023 +0000

bar4...
```

How can I achieve that, given only the values from the `--first-parent` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the two-dot syntax of `log` is shorthand for the exclusion operator (`^`):

```
git log A..B
# is the same as
git log B ^A
```

In words that says:

> Show me all commits reachable by `B` that aren't reachable by `A`.

When either `A` or `B` is a direct descendant of the other, then you'll end up excluding everything if you reverse them. This becomes more obvious when you say it out loud:

```
git log 5485e88..2449d02
```

Would be in words:

> Show me all commits reachable by 2449d02 that are not reachable by 5485e88.

If you stare at your graph while saying that it'll be clear that's it's backwards.

**Side Note:** Diff with 2 dots is the same as diff with no dots:

```
git diff A B
# is the same as
git diff A..B
```

I find [this summary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69559520/184546) to be helpful when thinking about 2 dots vs 3 dots, and how they are kind of opposite between `log` and `diff`.

Answer (score 2):

The order is wrong. You are inadvertently asking for `git log merge2..merge1`.

If you instead enter `git log 2449d02..5485e88` (FROM foo TO bar) you will get the commits AFTER "Feature foo" up to and including "Feature bar". Note that commit 2449d02 "Feature foo" will not appear.